# can we use XPath with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape an URL and I had the following code, to find the `td` tag whose class is `'empformbody'`:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url =  "http://www.example.com/servlet/av/ResultTemplate=AVResult.html"
req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page)

soup.findAll('td',attrs={'class':'empformbody'})
```

Now in the above code we can use `findAll` to get tags and information related to them, but I want to use XPath. Is it possible to use XPath with BeautifulSoup? If possible, please provide me example code.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Nope, BeautifulSoup, by itself, does not support XPath expressions.

An alternative library, [lxml](http://lxml.de/), *does* support XPath 1.0. It has a [BeautifulSoup compatible mode](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) where it'll try and parse broken HTML the way Soup does. However, the [default lxml HTML parser](http://lxml.de/parsing.html) does just as good a job of parsing broken HTML, and I believe is faster.

Once you've parsed your document into an lxml tree, you can use the `.xpath()` method to search for elements.

```
try:
    # Python 2
    from urllib2 import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml import etree

url =  "http://www.example.com/servlet/av/ResultTemplate=AVResult.html"
response = urlopen(url)
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(response, htmlparser)
tree.xpath(xpathselector)
```

There is also a [dedicated `lxml.html()` module](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) with additional functionality.

Note that in the above example I passed the `response` object directly to `lxml`, as having the parser read directly from the stream is more efficient than reading the response into a large string first. To do the same with the `requests` library, you want to set `stream=True` and pass in the `response.raw` object [after enabling transparent transport decompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests/13137873#13137873):

```
import lxml.html
import requests

url =  "http://www.example.com/servlet/av/ResultTemplate=AVResult.html"
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
response.raw.decode_content = True
tree = lxml.html.parse(response.raw)
```

Of possible interest to you is the [CSS Selector support](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html); the `CSSSelector` class translates CSS statements into XPath expressions, making your search for `td.empformbody` that much easier:

```
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector

td_empformbody = CSSSelector('td.empformbody')
for elem in td_empformbody(tree):
    # Do something with these table cells.
```

Coming full circle: BeautifulSoup itself *does* have very complete [CSS selector support](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for cell in soup.select('table#foobar td.empformbody'):
    # Do something with these table cells.
```

Comment: Thanks very much Pieters, i got two informations from ur code,1. A clarification that we can't use xpath with BS 2.A nice example on how using lxml. Can we see it on a particular documentation that "we can't implement xpath using BS in written form", because we should show some proof to someone those who ask for clarification right?

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative; the [BeautifulSoup 4 documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) has a search function and there are no hits for 'xpath'.

Comment: I tried running your code above but got an error "name 'xpathselector' is not defined"

Comment: @Zvi the code doesn’t define an Xpath selector; I meant it to be read as “use your own XPath expression *here*”.

Answer (score 206):

I can confirm that there is no XPath support within Beautiful Soup.

Comment: Note: Leonard Richardson is the author of Beautiful Soup, as you'll see if you click through to his user profile.

Comment: It would be very nice to be able to use XPATH within BeautifulSoup

Comment: So what is the alternative?

Comment: @leonard-richardson It's 2021, are you still confirming that BeautifulSoup *STILL* does not have xpath support?

Answer (score 64):

As others have said, BeautifulSoup doesn't have xpath support.  There are probably a number of ways to get something from an xpath, including using Selenium.  However, here's a solution that works in either Python 2 or 3:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
#This will create a list of buyers:
buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')
#This will create a list of prices
prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')

print('Buyers: ', buyers)
print('Prices: ', prices)
```

I used [this](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/) as a reference.

Comment: One warning: I've noticed if there is something outside the root (like a \n outside the outer <html> tags), then referencing xpaths by the root will not work, you have to use relative xpaths. https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html

Comment: *Martijn's code no longer works properly (it is 4+ years old by now...), the etree.parse() line prints to the console and doesn't assign the value to the tree variable.* That's quite a claim. I certainly can't reproduce that, and it would *not make any sense*. Are you sure you are using Python 2 to test my code with, or have translated the `urllib2` library use to Python 3 `urllib.request`?

Comment: Yeah, that may be the case that I used Python3 when writing that and it didn't work as expected.  Just tested and yours works with Python2, but Python3 is much preferred as 2 is being sunset (no longer officially supported) in 2020.

Comment: absolutely agree, but the question here *uses Python 2*.

Answer (score 25):

```
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('path of your localfile.html'),'html.parser')
dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
print dom.xpath('//*[@id="BGINP01_S1"]/section/div/font/text()')
```

*Above used the combination of Soup object with lxml and one can extract the value using xpath*

Answer (score 24):

BeautifulSoup has a function named [findNext](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html#find-all-next-and-find-next) from current element directed childern,so:

```
father.findNext('div',{'class':'class_value'}).findNext('div',{'id':'id_value'}).findAll('a')
```

Above code can imitate the following xpath:

```
div[class=class_value]/div[id=id_value]
```

Answer (score 4):

when you use lxml all simple:

```
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
i_need_element = tree.xpath('//a[@class="shared-components"]/@href')
```

but when use BeautifulSoup BS4 all simple too:

- first remove "//" and "@"
- second - add star before "="

try this magic:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
i_need_element = soup.select ('a[class*="shared-components"]')
```

as you see, this does not support sub-tag, so i remove "/@href" part

Comment: `select()` is for CSS selectors, it's not XPath at all. _as you see, this does not support sub-tag_ While I'm not sure if that was true at the time, it certainly isn't now.

Answer (score 3):

I've searched through their [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and it seems there is no XPath option.

Also, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814750/how-can-i-translate-this-xpath-expression-to-beautifulsoup) on a similar question on SO, the OP is asking for a translation from XPath to BeautifulSoup, so my conclusion would be - no, there is no XPath parsing available.

Comment: yes actually until now i used scrapy which uses xpath to fetch the data inside tags.Its very handy and easy to fetch data, but i got a need to do the same with beautifulsoup so looking forward in to it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the following without XPath

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html = '''
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
'''
# What XPath can do, so can it
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
# The result is the same as doc.getElementByTag('body').getElementByTag('div').getElementByTag('h1').text
print (doc.body.div.h1.text)
print (doc.div.h1.text)
print (doc.h1.text) # Shorter paths will be faster
print (doc.div.getChildren())
print (doc.div.getChildren('p'))
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a pretty old thread, but there is a work-around solution now, which may not have been in BeautifulSoup at the time.

Here is an example of what I did. I use the "requests" module to read an RSS feed and get its text content in a variable called "rss_text". With that, I run it thru BeautifulSoup, search for the xpath /rss/channel/title, and retrieve its contents. It's not exactly XPath in all its glory (wildcards, multiple paths, etc.), but if you just have a basic path you want to locate, this works.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
rss_obj = BeautifulSoup(rss_text, 'xml')
cls.title = rss_obj.rss.channel.title.get_text()
```

Comment: I believe this only finds the child elements. XPath is another thing?

Comment: This is just the regular navigation provided by BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score -5):

use   `soup.find(class_='myclass')`