# Extracting semi-structured user generated content from web pages using Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am working on a project for which I need to extract chords played over song lyrics.
The goal is to find what part of lyrics are played under which chord.
I'm using web pages containing guitar chords from ultimate-guitar.com (I chose this site because it seems to have largest collection of transcribed songs)

The typical structure of web page is:

For example:
http://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/p/poets_of_the_fall/carnival_of_rust_crd.htm

Snippet:
[image]

As you can see, the chords are written on line before lyrics and the relative position from left margin decides which chord is played over which words.
The page source for the above song looks like:
[image]

My strategy to accomplish the task:

1. Find the above relevant portion (ignore ads, indexes on web page) of web page using beautiful soup
2. Read this portion line by line.
3. Use `<span>` tag to identify which lines contain chords.
4. Assume the next line following line having  tags is going to contain
5. Find out relative position of each chord, store it and compare it to position of words in line below to find out which chords are played over what chords.
6. Store this data in a dictionary with chord name as key and value would be list of phrases played over this key chord.

The above implementation works fine in some cases, but since there's no specific structure defined, it fails miserably whenever the assumed structure of page is not followed.

For example, (Source: http://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/k/kate_voegele/all_i_see_crd.htm)

[image]

Here there are unexpected `<pre><i></i>` tags before `<span>` and now my key is stored as `<\pre><i></i>D` instead of just `D`.

And there are many such errors in my parsed data because of this unexpected variation in structure of page.
Any ideas on how these kind of cases could be handled or is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you encountered "unexpected variation".

So the only way to handle those cases is to, well, include that into your logic (e.g., if we find `<i></i>` tag, then ignore)

Comment: I get your point and could use this suggestion if the data set was small. But I have around 25000 files with some files having different tags which makes following this approach difficult. It would be difficult to manually check each file and add an exception rule for each case in my code.

Comment: I'm not saying that you should do that for each specific case. You can (and should) make the exception logic general (through guessing what kind of exception might occur), because that's actually what you as human do when you look at the code. There's no way the code will be able to recognize which ones are exceptional case unless you include that as part of the logic. You can do something like cleaning the HTML first (e.g., removing any tags inside `<pre></pre>` tags which is not in the form of `<span>#CHORD_NAME#</span>`).

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your earlier comment. Thanks for clarifying it further! But I'm currently learning to use lxml to check if I can make use of it and simplify my code. If not, then this seems the correct path to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You'd benefit a lot from using XPath. (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)

Unfortunately BeautifulSoup doesn't support it. Consider using lxml instead.

http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#using-xpath-to-find-text

According to this stackoverflow post, you can get it to be tolerant of broken HTML/XML documents.

[can we use xpath with BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup)