# Is there any way to keep calling findChildren in BeautifulSoup with more concision?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I know Beautiful Soup does not support xpath expressions. Thus I end up writing code that looks like this:

```
soup.findChildren(['table'])[0].findChildren(['tr'])[0].findChildren(['td'])[0]
```

UGLY! Is there a cleaner and more direct way to write these kinds of chains without xpath using Beautiful Soup. I do not want to use lxml because it has trouble parsing my HTML.

[can we use xpath with BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: You are specifying which of all tables and which of its rows you want the children of, looks concise to me ( well, precise, at least). What would an XPath query look like that would be easier on the eyes?

Comment: One Google search and I found at least one solution to your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup