# Locating table with no id or class attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a site with a few tables.  Neither table has a class or an id and the site really doesn't use either one so I am not sure if there is a way for me to get the data.
Here is the link to the site - I would post the html but it would be too long.

http://epi.hbsna.com/products/dept.asp?msi=0&sid=6076533CE8C648AE9883BDDBED795B29&dept_id=315&parent_id=0

The table I am trying to extract begins on line 310.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this is `BeautifulSoup` specific question, here is a working `BeautifulSoup` specific solution. The idea is to find the element having the `SKU#` text and [locate the first `table` parent](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = requests.get('http://epi.hbsna.com/products/dept.asp?msi=0&sid=6076533CE8C648AE9883BDDBED795B29&dept_id=315&parent_id=0').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

table = soup.find(text="SKU#").find_parent("table")
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    print([cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all("td")])
```

Prints the contents of the table:

```
['40010001', 'ABA Service Kit', '-', '1-1/4" 10', 'None', '5-1/2"', '0.63', 'Clamp', '42710566']
['40010002', 'ABA Service Kit', '-', '1-1/4" 10', '5/8" RH', '5-1/2"', '0.63', 'Clamp', '42710566']
...
['40010649', 'ABA Service Kit', '-', '1 1/2 - 10', '1.5', '6"', '0.50', 'Strap', '427-10517']
['40050604', 'ABA Service Kit', 'none', '1 1/2" - 10"', '1 1/2" LH', '6"', '0.50', 'Strap', '427-10601']
```

Comment: Thank you - that looks perfect - does this code work for 3.5 - I am getting some errors

Comment: @PatrickP76 yeah, tested on 3.5. What error do you get? Thanks.

Comment: Do not worry - I was able to figure it out - you are the best - I just had to change the request to the 3.5 version

Answer (score 2):

How do you feel about using this `xpath` expression?

```js
//*[./text()="SKU#"]/ancestor::table[1]
```

It means, "find the first element with text being exactly SKU#, then select its closest table ancestor."

You can try it out in a browser inspector by passing the expression as a string to the `$x` function.

---

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup) for working with `xpath` in `beautifulsoup`.

Comment: If there's a risk that SKU# will appear elsewhere in the document, you can choose any other bit of text that will always appear only in the table.

Comment: I am new and haven't tried or even heard of xpath - I will research and hopefully that will do it.  Thank you.

Comment: @alecxe's answer is perfect for using just `beautifulsoup`, and it reads very clearly! `xpath` is a language for navigating xml documents that has implementations in most programming languages. It's worth checking out as a part of your web scraping toolkit. :)