# Find xapth in beautifulsoup to get target tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have Html structure like

```
<html>
<body>
    <-- Some tags -->
    <div class="main-sv">
         <div class="first-sv custom-sv">
            <-- Some tags and content-->
         </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

I want to check out if class value of first child of `div` which class value is `main-sv` and child tag is div and class value contains `First-sv` sub-string.

Following in my code which work fine

```
>>> "Frist-sv" in dict(soup.find("div", {"class" :"main-sv"}).findChild().attrs)["class"].split(" ")
True
```

still any other way like `xpath` in `lxml` ?

I have to use **beautifulsoup** only

Answer (score 0):

No, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup) BeautifulSoup itself does not support xpath look-up. But here is a slightly more simplified solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="main-sv">
     <div class="first-sv custom-sv">
        <-- Some tags and content-->
     </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print 'first-sv' in soup.find('div', {'class':'main-sv'}).find('div')['class']
# prints True
```

Or another one, using *select*

```
parent = soup.find('div', {'class':'main-sv'})
child = parent.select('div')[0]
print 'first-sv' in child['class']
# prints True
```