# python3 to parse html part with xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath

I just want to extract div part html part from the following html with path xpath.
I just give some part of this link html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Items 1 to 20 -- Example Page 1</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _ gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-23648880-1']);
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
   _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'econpy.org']);
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
  <div align="center">1, <a    
       href="http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/002.html">[<font    
   color="green">2</font>]</a>, <a    
   href="http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/003.html">[<font 
   color="green">3</font>]</a>, <a   
   href="http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/004.html">[<font 
   color="green">4</font>]</a>, <a 
  href="http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/005.html">[<font 
 color="green">5</font>]</a></div>
#I just want to get this part html.
<div class ="item-body" 
 <div title="item1">
 <div title="buyer-name">Carson Busses</div>
 <span class="item-price">$29.95</span><br>
</div>
</div  
.......
<div title="buyer-info">
<div title="buyer-name">Earl E. Byrd</div>
<span class="item-price">$8.37</span><br>
</div>
<div title="buyer-info">
<div title="buyer-name">Patty Cakes</div>
<span class="item-price">$15.26</span><br>
</div>
<div title="buyer-info">
<div title="buyer-name">Derri Anne Connecticut</div>
<span class="item-price">$19.25</span><br>
</div>
<div title="buyer-info">
<div title="buyer-name">Moe Dess</div>
<span class="item-price">$19.25</span><br>
</div>
<div title="buyer-info">
<div title="buyer-name">Leda Doggslife</div>
<span class="item-price">$13.99</span><br>
</div>
.........
.........
<div title="buyer-info">
<div title="buyer-name">Rose Tattoo</div>
<span class="item-price">$114.07</span><br>
</div>
<div title="buyer-info">
<div title="buyer-name">Moe Tell</div>
<span class="item-price">$10.09</span><br>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">  (function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script');     ga.type =     
'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:'   == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl'     
: 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want to extract the following part html in this html link.

```
 <div class ="item-body" 
 <div title="item1">
  <div title="buyer-name">Carson Busses</div>
 <span class="item-price">$29.95</span><br>
</div>
</div
```

my code is:

```
  from lxml import html
  from lxml import etree
  import requests

  page = requests.get('001.html')
  tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
  buy_info2 = tree.xpath('//div[contains(@title, "item-body")]')
  print("buy-info2: ", buy_info2)
```

I hope it get the html list, but the result is [ ], Please give you hand to help me and please use the xpath not other method. Thanks!

Comment: May be your solution is here [use xpath with BeautifulSoup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup) try this one.

Comment: I just want to use the xpath method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue, just use the following code, add the //* in my code, it works:

```
 buy_info2 = tree.xpath('//div[contains(@title, "item-body")]//*')
```

then I can I get all the html element that I want to.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the div using the class name:

```
In [2]: from lxml import html

In [3]: xml = html.fromstring(h)

In [4]: div = xml.xpath("//div[@class='item-body']")[0]

In [5]: print(html.tostring(div))
<div class="item-body" title="item1">
 <div title="buyer-name">Carson Busses</div>
 <span class="item-price">$29.95</span><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for  your answer.