# Given list of websites, search and return information in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-search

I created a function that returns a list of urls given a specific companies name. I want to know search through this list of urls and find information on whether the company is owned by another company.

Example: The company "Marketo" was acquired by Adobe.

I want to return whether some company was acquired and by whom.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from googlesearch import search
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


def get_url(company_name):
    url_list = []
    for url in search(company_name, stop=10):
        url_list.append(url)
    return url_list


test1 = get_url('Marketo')
print(test1[7])


r = requests.get(test1[7])
html = r.text
soup = BS(html, 'lxml')
stuff = soup.find_all('a')


print(stuff)
```

I am new to web scraping and I have no idea how to really search through each URL (assuming I can) and find the information I seek.

The value of test1 is the following list:

```
['https://www.marketo.com/', 'https://www.marketo.com/software/marketing-automation/', 'https://blog.marketo.com/', 'https://www.marketo.com/software/', 'https://www.marketo.com/company/', 'https://www.marketo.com/solutions/pricing/', 'https://www.marketo.com/solutions/', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marketo', 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/marketo', 'https://www.cmswire.com/digital-marketing/what-is-marketo-a-marketers-guide/']
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299268/scraping-a-list-of-urls

Comment: Could you give us the value of the `test1` list ?

Comment: @Maaz just included the output

Comment: The information you are looking for in the wikipedia link is not so easy to find. There is not this information inside the infobox on the right, so you have to find it on the text using some language processing

Comment: @Maaz Yea I am not sure if wikipedia will be the right place to search. Overall I just want to be able to search through a list of urls to find specific information i.e. whether a particular company was acquired by another. Is that difficult? I feel like it must have been done before.

Comment: @Selcuk I don't really follow the link you provided at all for what I am trying to do.

Comment: I don't think what you are asking for is possible - to scrape information from a webpage, you have to know where you would find it on that webpage. There's no way you can guarantee that this information is even on a particular company's website - let alone in a "uniform" place on each one. You're probably better off looking for an API to get this kind of information - I see that for UK companies, for example, you could use [this](https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/). I don't know if other countries have anything similar.

Comment: Actually you are asking two questions: "Where to find?", and "How to scrape?". Better to place one question in one post. Also the first one isn't related to SO.

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](https://policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries. Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to return whether some company was acquired and by whom

You can scrape the [crunchbase](https://www.crunchbase.com/) website to get this information.The downside is that you will be limiting your search to their site. To extend this you could perhaps include some other sites also.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
while True:
    print()
    organization_name=input('Enter organization_name: ').strip().lower()
    crunchbase_url='https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/'+organization_name
    headers={
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
    }
    r=requests.get(crunchbase_url,headers=headers)
    if r.status_code == 404:
        print('This organization is not available\n')
    else:
        soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
        overview_h2=soup.find('h2',text=re.compile('Overview'))
        try:
            possible_acquired_by_span=overview_h2.find_next('span',class_='bigValueItemLabelOrData')
            if possible_acquired_by_span.text.strip() == 'Acquired by':
                acquired_by=possible_acquired_by_span.find_next('span',class_='bigValueItemLabelOrData').text.strip()
            else:
                acquired_by=False
        except Exception as e:
                acquired_by=False
                # uncomment below line if you want to see the error
                # print(e)
        if acquired_by:
            print('Acquired By: '+acquired_by+'\n')
        else:
            print('No acquisition information available\n')

    again=input('Do You Want To Continue? ').strip().lower()
    if  again not in ['y','yes']:
        break
```

Sample Output:

```
Enter organization_name: Marketo
Acquired By: Adobe Systems

Do You Want To Continue? y

Enter organization_name: Facebook
No acquisition information available

Do You Want To Continue? y

Enter organization_name: FakeCompany
This organization is not available

Do You Want To Continue? n
```

**Notes**

- Read the [crunchbase Terms](https://about.crunchbase.com/terms-of-service/) and seek their consent before you deploy this in any commercial projects.
- Also checkout the [crunchbase api](https://data.crunchbase.com/docs/using-the-api) - I think this will be the legit way to go forward with what you are asking for.

Comment: For the 'User Agent' part, I do not use a Linux machine so will this work for windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can find that information from site like Crunchbase.

The steps to get it are as follows:

1. build the url containing the information for your target company. Suppose you find the url containing the information you need like:

   `url = 'https://www.example.com/infoaboutmycompany.html'`
2. use selenium to get the html, as the site does not allow you to scrape the page directly. Something like this:

   `from selenium import webdriver
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   driver = webdriver.Firefox()
   driver.get(url)
   html = driver.page_source`
3. use BeautifulSoup to get the text from the div containing the information. It has a specific class, that you can easily find looking at the html:

   `bsobj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
   res = bsobj.find('div', {'class':'alpha beta gamma'})
   res.text.strip()`

Less than 10 lines of code to get it.

Of course, it works changing your list, from a list of urls to a list of companies, hopefully considered by that site. For marketo it works.

Comment: Could you expand your answer with an example? I will gladly accept your answer after I see a working solution.

Comment: I do not know whether this kind of scraping is completely fair. Probably someone from the stackoverflow staff should consent the plain code. Anyway I will give you a coding idea of each step.

Comment: I just started looking at it now, what is the 'alpha beta gamma', is that just something you are trying to find the html?

Comment: I do get a number of errors: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: If you would like to get the bounty it would help if you could provide an example in which I can copy and paste your code to understand what I will need to modify and change for my specific task. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the error with selenium, read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path

Comment: Regarding the 'alpha beta gamma', is just an idea of the class the div should satisfy. In your case, change with `flex-no-grow cb-overflow-ellipsis identifier-label`

Answer (score 1):

As mention by other answers **crunchbase** is a good place to get this type of information, but you will require a headless browser to scrape the crunchbase
such as **Selenium**

---

If you are using ubuntu installing Selenium is fairly easy. Selenium requires a driver to interface with the chosen browser. For example, Firefox requires geckodriver

- pip install selenium
- sudo pip3 install selenium --upgrade

install lastest version of geckodriver

- wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.24.0/geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz
- tar -xvzf geckodriver*
- chmod +x geckodriver

Add the driver to your PATH so other tools can find it or in the directory where all your software all install otherwise it will throw an error ('geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH)

- mv geckodriver /usr/bin/

---

**code**

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from selenium import webdriver


baseurl = "https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/{0}"

query = input('type company name : ').strip().lower()
url = baseurl.format(query)

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BS(html, 'lxml')
acquiredBy = soup.find('div', class_= 'flex-no-grow cb-overflow-ellipsis identifier-label').text


print(acquiredBy)
```

---

You can also get other information using the same logic just inspect the class/ id and the scrape the information.