# How to implement logic of xpath in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup

I have one xpath and I need to use same logic in beautifulsoup

XPATH = `.//li/a[@class="js-pagination"][text()!="Next"]`

I need to write something like this

```
pg = soup.find_all('li').findNext('a',attrs={"class":"js-pagination:"})
```

I don't know what to do next help me to do it

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: You could at least paste above the relevant html elements. Your defined class names are different in two expressions. Anyways, BeautifulSoup doesn't support xpah but it does support css selectors which is more robust and concise.