# Web Scrape Second <b> tag in single <div>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape using beautifulsoup the first and second  tags (-130, and +110) in this single HTML div (as seen below):
[example HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7zuM.png)

However I can not figure out how to scrape the second tag, can only scrape the first. Thank you.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

day = "09"
month = "10"
year = "2017"
my_url = 'https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/mlb-baseball/?date=' + year + month + day

# Opening up the connection and grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

allBovadaOdds = page_soup.find_all("div", {"rel": "999996"})

firstOdds = allBovadaOdds[1].b.string
print(firstOdds)
```

Comment: XPath is your friend. `//div/b[2]` will find the second `b` in each `div`; `//div[@rel="9999996"]/b[2]`, will find the second `b` only in a `div` that has a `rel` attribute with the given value (remove the `@` if you want to look for an element, not an attribute).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, maybe I'm missing something here, but, XPath can't be used with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar, modern versions of BeautifulSoup by default backend into lxml, which very much does support XPath.

Comment: Do you mean `lxml.etree`?

Comment: Actually, I mean `lxml.html`. See http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html, and https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Comment: Thanks, got it. Sorry for the confusion. I was basing my comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11469854/7832176).

Comment: Note the date on that answer -- it was true for BS3.

Answer (score 2):

What you want can be written fairly simply, I think.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/mlb-baseball/?date=20171009').text
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> soup.select('#eventLine-3330496-43 b')
[<b>-130</b>, <b>+110</b>]
>>> for item in soup.select('#eventLine-3330496-43 b'):
...     item.text
...     
'-130'
'+110'
```

However, I notice two potential problems:

- The labelling of the elements (ie, ids of divs, etc) might vary from one invocation of the web page to the next.
- There are actually two columns with this pair of values. It might be safer to identify the required items by using booking agent and number for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `soup.select()` filter tags and use  `for i in range():` to get all of the second  tags. Note that the step in `range()` should be `2`.

```
# html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
allBovadaOdds = page_soup.select('div[rel="999996"] b')
print(allBovadaOdds)
for i in range(1,len(allBovadaOdds),2):
    SecondOdds = allBovadaOdds[i].string
    print(SecondOdds)
```