# Do a "ctrl+F" on a webpage using a python script...

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to make a script that compute a "ctrl F"?

I have a list of societies. I want to get (for exemple) the values of those societies.

For each society of my list my script:
- go on google
- type the name of the society
- click on search
- go to the first url

And now, I am on the good website. 
I want to go through all the pages and look for the word "value" (= do a ctrl F) to collect a list of word behind...

The idea is to get the list of values of each society...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with an xpath selector.

In this [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup) you can see how you can use xpath selectors with beautifulsoup.

The xpath expression to search for the text "value" would be something like:

```
//*[text()="value"]
```

If you need to improve this expression, refer to [this great guide](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) about xpath expressions.