# Python, extract urls from xml sitemap that contain a certain word

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract all urls from a sitemap that contain the word foo in the url. I've managed to extract all the urls but can't figure out how to only get the ones I want. So in the below example I only want the urls for apples and pears returned.

```
<url>
<loc>
https://www.example.com/p-1224-apples-foo-09897.php
</loc>
<lastmod>2018-05-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
https://www.example.com/p-1433-pears-foo-00077.php
</loc>
<lastmod>2018-05-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
https://www.example.com/p-3411-oranges-ping-66554.php
</loc>
<lastmod>2018-05-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modify the xml to valid format (add `<urls>` and `</urls>`), save them into src.xml:

```
<urls>
<url>
<loc>
https://www.example.com/p-1224-apples-foo-09897.php
</loc>
<lastmod>2018-05-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
https://www.example.com/p-1433-pears-foo-00077.php
</loc>
<lastmod>2018-05-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
https://www.example.com/p-3411-oranges-ping-66554.php
</loc>
<lastmod>2018-05-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
</urls>
```

Use `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse xml:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse('src.xml')
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> for url in root.findall('url'):
...     for loc in url.findall('loc'):
...             if loc.text.__contains__('foo'):
...                     print(loc.text)
...

https://www.example.com/p-1224-apples-foo-09897.php
https://www.example.com/p-1433-pears-foo-00077.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they are always in elements `loc` tagged then you can use an XPath method

```
//loc[contains(text(),'foo')]
```

Generic would be:

```
//*[contains(text(),'foo')]
```

It requires using `lxml` which supports XPath, see [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 1):

If you have all the urls then you can check for each url if the word "foo" is in it by using `in`. Something like this (assuming you already have all the urls in a list called `urls`):

```
urls = [url for url in urls if 'foo' in url]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom
xml_file = r'your_file.xml'
DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse(xml_file)
root_node = DOMTree.documentElement
print(root_node.nodeName)
loc_nodes = root_node.getElementsByTagName("loc")
for loc in loc_nodes:
    print(loc.childNodes[0].data)
```