# Need a python regular expression that can verify names with special characters(Hyphens, apostrophes, etc...)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a python regular expression that can match any name. I am scraping a web page and looking for the `<h1>` tag and grabbing the name in between it. The names can include **James Dean, James-Dean, Brian O'Quin, Jame Joe-Harden**, etc...

This was the first regular expression I have been working with but it is not catching all the names

```
<h1>[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\s[A-Z]{1}[']?[A-Z]?[-]?[A-Z]?[a-z]+
```

Comment: `{1}` is unneeded

Comment: Don’t use regexp for HTML or [He Comes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: why not [parse with an html library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11709079/1358308) then use an [xpath selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11466033/1358308) to match the appropriate tags

Comment: maybe you should explain better what you are looking for. You gave some examples, but didn't say *exactly* which characters you are trying to match

Comment: @LeonardoMaffei I am looking inside of html and looking for something like this <h1>name</h1> example  [link](http://www.espn.com/college-football/player/_/id/4360076/dylan-oquinn). I am trying to grab the player's name at the top of the page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
<h1>(([-'\w]+\s?)+)<h1>
```

Explaining:

the *-* matches itself, *\w* matches letters and numbers, and the *plus* is to capture one or more of these occurrences. Also, is optional a *space character* after this, to support composed names.
Finally, the last *+* plus ensures that you can repeat the structure I've just described.
Hope this help.

Comment: This is kinda working and I have been doing some testing and this is where I'm at the regular expression I have is `<h1>([-\'\w]+\s+\w+)` and when I try to extract the name **Dylan O'Quin** I return this **Dylan O** Any suggestions?

Comment: just add a *+* after the last parentheses. Compare the result through (regex101.com)[regex101] and you will understand your mistake. Basically, this plus will *keep* looking for the pattern ```([-\'\w]+\s+\w+)``` over and over again

Comment: @LeonardiMaffei Thank you for your help! I ended up having to many troubles with regex and found a different solution with a html parser and BeautifulSoup

Comment: The last <h1> in the answer needs to be </h1> though.

Comment: @MrLister In python regex the (/) in the closing header tag is an escape character. This is caused by any unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash (\) and will break the pattern matching. As before I found that using an html parser with Beautiful soup was much much much easier lol