# How to open links in Amazon using BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python, css, web-scraping

**Issue:** the “linkElems” list appears to be empty

**Suspect what is causing the issue:** I think the tags I’m telling it to grab is wrong

**Function of Program:**

- Search Amazon.com for arguments in command line and download the
  website into the variable “res”
- Select the URLs for the links of the
  results of the search and store them into a list called “linkElems”
- Open new browser tabs for the first 5 results

**Context:** I’ve finished Chapter 11 of Automate the Boring stuff and and using the same code from the first project except I’ve tweaked it a little bit to search Amazon search results instead of google.

**What Tags I’ve tried:**

- 'a'
- ‘h2. a’
- 'a.a-link-normal a-text-normal'
- '.h2 a'

```
#! python3
#Shop on Amazon - searchs amazon and opens the first 5 top results

import sys,requests,bs4,webbrowser,logging

print ('Searching')

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'
}

res = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/s?k=' + ''.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,features = 'html.parser')

linkElems = soup.select('a.a-link-normal a-text-normal')
numOpen = min(5, len(linkElems))
for i in range(numOpen):
    webbrowser.open('https://amazon.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

H**TML example of link I'm trying to grab using the tags:**

[Sample HTML That I'm searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBP4V.png)

[Example of me running the program and its output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFib2.png)

Comment: Check out the answer on this post ! It may help. The problem is similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: @francovici Thanks. I checked out that link but it doesn't quite solve my problem.In the previous project of the book it shows how the links from a google search are siblings of a "div r" class so i tried to do something similar with the Amazon search but it doesn't appear to be grabbing them so i figure I'm not understanding how to tell which tag to use.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your css selector `'a.a-link-normal a-text-normal'`. This will look for a `a-text-normal` tag inside an `a` tag with class `a-link-normal`.

`a-link-normal` and `a-text-normal` are *both* classes of the relevant `a` tag. You can express this in a css selector by chaining them like this: `'a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal'`. This denotes that you are looking for an `a` tag that has both class `a-link-normal` *and* `a-text-normal`.

This script for example will search amazon for your command line input, collect all the links (`links = soup.select('a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal')`) and then print out the `href` attribute for each link it found. At this point, all I can say is, it works on my machine.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from sys import argv


r = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com/s?k=" + '+'.join(argv[1:]))
r.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
links = soup.select('a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal')

for tag in links:
    print(tag.attrs['href'])
```

Comment: Now that you mention it, the selector does look like it wasn't gonna work the way it was expressed. Looks like the space should be a period, just like you mentioned. ( a.a-link-normal a-text-normal  -> a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal )

Comment: @isaactfa I see what you're saying. I took some time to try it and experiment but i still can't get it. I'll edit my post to include one of the pieces of HTML i'm attempting to grab using the tag.

Comment: I have amended an example script to my answer. If this doesn't do it for you, there may be something wrong with the way you're getting your HTML.

Comment: interesting. I copy and pasted your code into a test program and it still doesn't do anything. I will continue to experiment and research. i'll leave this open in case i find the answer so that the information can be out there.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Are you getting nothing? What input are you giving?

Comment: I don't get an error, just no output when I ran your version of the code. In command line I type in "SoA cup" (SoA is the name of my program and cup is what I'm searching for) I have it print "Searching" in there so that I know it ran. I'm adding a screenshot so you can see it. You'll see I ran your version that i named "test".

Comment: This is confusing to me. Why aren't you running something like `> python test.py cup`?

Comment: This is how the book "Automate the Boring Stuff" tells me how to run it. It uses a .bat file to run it from command line. You can see that it runs. I tried it your way and its the same result.

Comment: And what's inside the .bat file? My Python code? Because that wouldn't work.

Comment: Last suggestion: paste my code into a file called `test.py`. From the command line navigate to where `test.py` is located on your system. Once you're in the same directory as `test.py` run `python test.py cup`.

Comment: 'at'py.exe C:\MyPythonScripts\test.py
'at'pause
(wouldn't let me use the actual 'at' sign in the comments here)
This is just so that i can use "test XXXX" to run the program from a regular command line.

Comment: Those two first 'at' lines are on separate lines but the comment box messed up the formatting.

Comment: Okay, just go to `C:\MyPythonScripts` from the command line, and run `python test.py cup`.

Comment: I did and it's the same result as my version.

Comment: But it works. I'm literally running it right now and it works exactly as expected. You gotta be doing something wrong. I can't help you.

Comment: Dang it. This is so frustrating. Thank you for trying to help though.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. I printed the raise for status result and I'm getting a 503 error so I think Amazon is blocking my scraper.