# How to collect data from website when wanted tag haven't class?

Tags: python

I would know how to get data from a website
I find a tutorial and finished with this

```py
import os
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

requete = requests.get("https://www.palabrasaleatorias.com/mots-aleatoires.php")
page = requete.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

The tutorial say me that I should use something like this to get the string of a tag

```py
h1 = soup.find("h1", {"class": "ico-after ico-tutorials"})
print(h1.string)
```

But I got a problem : the tag where I want to get text content haven't class... how should I do ?

I tried to put `{}` but not working
this too `{"class": ""}`
In fact, it's return me a None
I want to get the text content of this part of the website :

```html
<div style="font-size:3em; color:#6200C5;">
Orchard</div>
```

Where `Orchard` is the random word
Thank for any type of help

Comment: Is it *within* anything that's easier to select? From what you've given us it's really hard to suggest anything.

Comment: I dont understand what exactly you want ....do you want get this information ? ..  https://ibb.co/WxyCLYV

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there aren't many pointers featured in `BeautifulSoup`, and the page you are trying to get is terribly ill-suited for your task (no IDs, classes, or other useful html features to point at).

Hence, you should change the way you use to point at the html element, and use the Xpath - and you can't do it with `BeautifulSoup`. In order to do that, just use `html` from package `lxml` to parse the page. Below a code snippet (based on the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup)) which extracts the random word in your example.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

requete = requests.get("https://www.palabrasaleatorias.com/mots-aleatoires.php")
tree = html.fromstring(requete.content)
rand_w = tree.xpath('/html/body/center/center/table[1]/tr/td/div/text()')
print(rand_w)
```