# Python get html element by Xpath

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml

I try to get an HTML Element by the XPath, I tried it this way but it always returns an empty String.
Can anybody tell me, how I get the Element by its X-Path ?

```
    for x in list_href_einrichtungen:

      url = 'https://pflegefinder.bkk-dachverband.de/' + x
      source_code = requests.get(url)
      plain_text = source_code.text
      soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)

      **doc = lxml.html.fromstring(source_code.content)
      strasse = doc.xpath('div[3]/div[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div[1]/p[1]/text()[1]')**

      name = soup.find('h2').text
      uebergabeeinrichtung = Einrichtung("IK", name, 'Teststraße', '12345', 'Ort', "telefon", 
      'Telefax', 'email','internet')

      list_einrichtungen.append(uebergabeeinrichtung)
      print(name,  strasse)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can we use xpath with BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 2):

Sie können kein Element mit Beautifulsoup mit XPATH finden. Eine andere Library, die Sie benutzten können heisst 'lxml'. Das steht hier in StackOverflow. Als Beispiel:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml import etree

url =  "http://www.example.com/servlet/av/ResultTemplate=AVResult.html"
response = urlopen(url)
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(response, htmlparser)
tree.xpath(xpathselector)
```

Ich hoffe, dass das geholfen hat!

pd: sorry fürs Deutsch, ich lerne gerade ;)

Comment: Hallo,danke für deine Antwort, ich habe es auch schon mit lxml versucht und leider klappt es damit auch nicht.                                                                                                      CODE:                                                                                       
 response = urlopen(url)
        htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
        tree = etree.parse(response, htmlparser)
        strasse =tree.xpath('//*[@id="page"]/div[3]/div[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div[1]/p[3]/text()[1]')

Comment: Hast du auch mit ID-finden versucht?