# Extracting everything between two lxml tags Python

Tags: python, html, tags, lxml

Consider the following html snippet

```html
<html>
  .
  .
  .
  <div>
    <p> Hello </p>
    <div>
      <b>
        Text1
      </b>
      <p>
        This is a huge paragraph text
      </p>
       .
       .
       .
     </div>
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
  <div>
    <i>
      Text2
    </i>
  </div>
```

Let us say that I need to extract everything from `Text1` to `Text2`, including the tags. 
Using a few methods, I have been able to extract the tags of those two, i.e. their unique ID.

Essentially I have 2 Element.etree elements, corresponding to the two tags I require.

How do I extract everything in between the two tags?

(One possible solution I can think of is to find the two tags common ancestor, and do a `iterwalk()` and start extracting at Element1, and stop at 2. However, I'm not exactly sure how this would be)
Any solution would be appreciated.

Please note that I have already found the two tags that I require, and I'm not looking for solutions to find those tags (for eg using xpath)

Edit: My desired output is

```html
      <b>
        Text1
      </b>
      <p>
        This is a huge paragraph text
      </p>
       .
       .
       .
     </div>
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
  <div>
    <i>
      Text2
    </i>
```

Please note that I wouldn't mind the initial 2 `<div>` tags, but do not want the `Hello`.
The same goes with the closing tags of the end. I'm mostly interested in the inbetween contents.

Edit 2: I have extracted the Etree elements using complex xpath conditions, which was not feasible with other alternatives such as bs4, so any solution using the lxml elements would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you provide the *desired output* ?

Comment: I have edited my post with the desired output. Apologies

Comment: You should think about working with regular expressions

Comment: The output might not be in a correct `xml` structure, is it problematic ?

Comment: No it wouldnt be a problem. I'm mostly interested in extracting the text inbetween

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After review and questioning:

```
from essentials.tokening import CreateToken # This was imported just to generate a random string - pip install mknxgn_essentials
import bs4

HTML = """<html>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="start">
                Hello, My name is mark
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        This is in the middle
    </div>

    <div>
        <div id="end">
            This is the end
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        Do not include this.
    </div>

</html>"""

RandomString = CreateToken(30, HTML) #Generate a random string that could never occur on it's own in the file, if it did occur, use something else 
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, features="lxml") # Convert the text into soup
start_div = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "start"}) #assuming you can find this element
start_div.insert_before(RandomString) # insert the random string before this element
end_div = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "end"})     #again, i was assuming you can also find this element
end_div.insert_after(RandomString) # insert the random string after this element

print(str(soup).split(RandomString)[1]) # Get between both random strings
```

The output of this returns:

```
>>>             <div id="start">
>>>                 Hello, My name is mark
>>>             </div>
>>>     </div>
>>> </div>
>>>     <div>
>>>         This is in the middle
>>>     </div>
>>> <div>
>>>     <div id="end">
>>>         This is the end
>>>     </div>
```

Comment: Hi. Initially I was using beautifulsoup, but switched to lxml because my problem isnt as simple as findall('div'). Using complex xpath statements, I was able to zero in onto my exact Etree elements, and this however, was not supported by beautifulsoup. 
So, now that I have my lxml unique elements, how can I approach this problem?

Comment: Hi @ShrutheeshRaman, can you give me an example of what your trying to get accomplished other than the one you have already provided?
From what you just explained, are you trying to: Collect everything from X to Y where they could possible be in different parent trees?

Comment: Hi @Mark, yes, I am trying to do exactly what you formulated. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61476144/9926472 This was my earlier question, and I followed the solution given in the link. Using a combination of regex and xpath condition provided in that solution, I was able to locate my two lxml elements E1 and E2. Now I wish to collect everything from E1 to E2 (which may be in different trees, like you said).

Comment: Oh great! This is a fantastic solution, never thought of this! Thanks.