# Get the text from a div tag in html with bs4 python

Tags: python, flask, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a website and I wan't to pull the text form a div tag with bs4 using an external website. and this is a flask website

```
#Importing librarys 
from flask import Flask, render_template 
import sys
import json
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#Importing files and class from other python files in the project
sys.path.append('.')
from webScrape import getInformation

#Making a new app instance
app = Flask(__name__)

#Saying if the app is on route / the open index.html
@app.route('/')
def index():
    URL = 'https://covidstat.info/home'

    HTML = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML.text, "html.parser")
    tag = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'count'})
    print(tag.text)
    return render_template('index.html', tag=tag)

#Running the app on port 5000
if __name__== '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0',)
```

Oh and I have another question anyone know how I can get an element using xpath in bs4

Comment: Oh and I have another question anyone know how I can get an element using xpath in bs4

Comment: what is the problem with your code are you getting any error

Comment: No I am getting this [<div class="count">2,735,342</div>, <div class="count">2,025,878</div>, <div class="count">329,757</div>, <div class="count">442</div>, <div class="count">4</div>, <div class="count">2,615,920</div>]

Comment: If I know now to use xpath with bs4 it should solve my issue

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/11466033/9050514

Comment: I am using python3 not python2

Comment: you can use lxml in python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `soup.findAll` you will return a list of divs in this case. For this reason you have to access them individually in a loop. You can also use a list comprehension like this:

`tag_text = [t.text for t in tag]`

Which returns: 
`['2,735,342', '2,025,878', '329,757', '442', '4', '2,615,920']`

Alternatively, you can use `soup.find` instead, which will just return the first div, and you could access it directly by `tag.text` which will give `'2,735,342'`.

To get the element by xpath is to use the inspector, by right-clicking on the text you want -> `Inspect Element` -> right click on the div-tag -> `Copy` -> `XPath`.

The xpath for the number used before would be:

`/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div[2]`

As of my knowledge, BS4 does not support xpath selection, so you'ld have to change to another library. I know Selenium supports it, but would probably not be the best use-case for this task.

Comment: Do you know how to split this up

Comment: Hi there, I'm not really sure what you mean by this question. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Sure, when I irate though the text it returns a list I wan't those values individually.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand 100%, but you can just index the list, e.g. tag_text[0] to get the first item and tag_text[-1] if you want the last one. Is this what you mean?