# Python Beautifulsoup cannot get svg tags

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

[image]I am trying to get each small circles that shows which result is banker or player.  I need to get the result from each 35 tables.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://ggl-maxim.com/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/input[1]').send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/input[2]').send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/button[1]').click()

time.sleep(2)
driver.get('http://ggl-maxim.com/api/popup/popup_menu.asp?mobile=0&lobby=EVOLUTION')

time.sleep(10)
html = driver.page_source
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
targets = bs.find_all('svg')

print(targets)
```

However, by this code I cannot get the svg tag. How can I?

Else, if anyone knows how to get this casino's value please tell me.

Comment: Why do you use driver.get two times? Which page are you testing?

Comment: Cause I need to send Evolution Game my user informations. Without that, I cannot see games working

Comment: Can you whow on a screenshot which circle you are looking for? There are >3000svgs

Comment: I edited it ! I need to make these records into list..

Comment: @Robinshim have you tried what I suggested? Does BeautifulSoup.find_all() support `xpath`?

Comment: No BeautifulSoup don't actually supports xpath

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Selenium I'd use css selector:

`driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".svg--1nrnH")`

Update for Selenium: wait for iframe. This is the reason why element could not be found.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get('http://ggl-maxim.com/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/input[1]').send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/input[2]').send_keys('tnrud3080')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/fieldset/button[1]').click()

time.sleep(2)
driver.get('http://ggl-maxim.com/api/popup/popup_menu.asp?mobile=0&lobby=EVOLUTION')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("gameIframe"))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".svg--1nrnH")))
targets = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".svg--1nrnH")
res = []
for el in targets:
    print(len(el.get_attribute("innerHTML")))
    res.append(el.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
print(*res, sep='\n')
```

Comment: If you see the capture at the top, I need those results to make into list.

Comment: Thanks ! I would have to find out how can I use those values into list..

Comment: You are welcome. It is possible but will require some more thinking.

Comment: well, I think it is hard to make record list  with x, y positions. I want more help.. Can you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232706/discussion-between-vitaliis-and-robin-shim).

Answer (score 0):

To find SVG tag use the below xpath :

```
//[name()='svg']
```

I see you are not switching to iframe and all the elements which you are trying to extract are in iframe so driver focus need to be switched to get all the desired element.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("gameIframe"))
```