# Getting value of a tag inside the same parent tag as a tag with a particular value

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

The title is a mouthful but describes what I want. I am parsing through an XML with BeautifulSoup. The format of my XML is as follows:

```
<properties>
    <place>
        <house_id>12345</house_id>
        <appliances>Fridge, Oven</appliances>
        <price>350000</price>
    </place>
    <place>
        <house_id>6789</house_id>
        <appliances>Heater, Microwave, Fridge</appliances>
        <price>870000</price>
    </place>
</properties>
```

Given a specific value for the `house_id` tag, I want the text INSIDE of the `appliances` that correspond to that place. For instance, given `12345`, I want to return `Fridge, Oven`. I have not found an easy way to do this yet with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. It is missing a root tag.

Comment: I'm just showing a snippet of it lol, not even the point of my question

Comment: Because you didn't provide a minimal reproducible example, here is not optimal XPath expression: `//place[house_id="12345"]/appliances`

Comment: I added one now

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [General Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) (`~`):

```
soup.select_one("house_id:-soup-contains('12345') ~ appliances").text
```

Or you can find the `<house_id>` tag containing specific text, and then call [`find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) to locate the `<appliances>` tag:

```
print(soup.find("house_id", text="12345").find_next("appliances").text)
```

Comment: Thank you! Would this work if appliances was not directly the next tag, but maybe a few down or a few previous ones?  I just gave dummy data to describe my question, in reality it wont be directly next, might be a few tags up or past it

Comment: @user3611 I think it should work even if it's not directly next. If it's upwards, you can use `find_previous()` instead of `find_next()`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input XML, the following XPath expression will produce what you need.

[can we use XPath with BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup)

**XPath**

```
/properties/place[house_id="12345"]/appliances
```

Comment: x path is not ideal as I have just shown you dummy data, in reality there are many many more tags and sometimes some tags are missing

Comment: I want to locate the features tag inside that specific place tag without needing to hardcode a path for it.

Comment: This also does not answer my question because xpath is not supported in BeautifulSoup.

Comment: My answer has a link for you

Answer (score 0):

This will work even if `<appliances>` tag is either before or after the `<house_id>`.

Use `findParent()` to find the parent of `<house_id>` and then find the tag `<appliances>` in that parent.

Here is the code

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """
<properties>
    <place>
        <house_id>12345</house_id>
        <appliances>Fridge, Oven</appliances>
        <price>350000</price>
    </place>
    <place>
        <house_id>6789</house_id>
        <appliances>Heater, Microwave, Fridge</appliances>
        <price>870000</price>
    </place>
    <place>
        <appliances>Oven, Cleaner, Microwave</appliances>
        <price>700000</price>
        <house_id>1296</house_id>
    </place>
</properties>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'xml')


def get_appliance(t, soup):
    h = soup.find('house_id', text=t)
    appliance = h.findParent().find('appliances')
    return appliance.text


print(get_appliance('12345', soup))
print(get_appliance('1296', soup))
```

```
Fridge, Oven
Oven, Cleaner, Microwave
```