# Problem with accessing XML-attributes via xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, beautifulsoup, elementtree

I have some `XML` that consists of a lot of repitions of the following xml-structure:

```
<record>
<header>
<identifier>oai:dnb.de/dnb:reiheO/1254645608</identifier><datestamp>2022-04-01T23:49:32Z</datestamp>
<setspec>dnb:reiheO</setspec>
</header>
<metadata>
<dc xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dnb="http://d-nb.de/standards/dnbterms" xmlns:tel="http://krait.kb.nl/coop/tel/handbook/telterms.html">
<dc:title>Advantages of Simultaneous In Situ Multispecies Detection for Portable Emission Measurement Applications / Luigi Biondo, Henrik Gerken, Lars Illmann, Tim Steinhaus, Christian Beidl, Andreas Dreizler, Steven Wagner</dc:title>
<dc:creator>Biondo, Luigi Verfasser]</dc:creator>
<dc:creator>Gerken, Henrik [Verfasser]</dc:creator>
<dc:creator>[Illmann, Lars [Verfasser]</dc:creator>
<dc:creator>Steinhaus, Tim [Verfasser]</dc:creator>
<dc:creator>Beidl, Christian [Verfasser]</dc:creator>
<dc:creator>Dreizler, Andreas [Verfasser]</dc:creator>
<dc:creator>Wagner, Steven [Verfasser]</dc:creator>
<dc:publisher>Darmstadt : Universitäts- und Landesbibliothek</dc:publisher>
<dc:date>2022</dc:date>
<dc:language>eng</dc:language>
<dc:identifier xsi:type="tel:URN">urn:nbn:de:tuda-tuprints-210508</dc:identifier>
<dc:identifier xsi:type="tel:URL">http://nbn-resolving.de/urn:nbn:de:tuda-tuprints-210508</dc:identifier>
<dc:identifier xsi:type="tel:URL">http://d-nb.info/1254645608/34</dc:identifier>
<dc:identifier xsi:type="tel:URL">http://tuprints.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/21050/</dc:identifier>
<dc:identifier xsi:type="dnb:IDN">1254645608</dc:identifier>
<dc:subject>670 Industrielle und handwerkliche Fertigung</dc:subject>
<dc:rights>lizenzfrei</dc:rights>
<dc:type>Online-Ressource</dc:type>
</dc>
</metadata>
</record>
```

Able to adress most of the elements and extract the information within, but  failing to get to the specific ones where I have to define the attribute as well. I think I am struggling with the `xpath`, but can't quite figure out, why.

If I try this code, I do get a list of elements, but it is empty:

```
urn = xml.find_all('.//dc:identifier[@xsi:type="tel:URN"]', namespaces=ns)
```

The same happens for the less specific version:

```
urn = xml.find_all('.//dc:identifier', namespaces=ns)
```

However, this code:  `test1 = xml.find_all("dc:identifier")` works and returns a lovely list of elements, but obviously not just of the identifiers specified as urn.

But this: `urn = xml.find_all('dc:identifier[@xsi:type="tel:URN"]', namespaces=ns)` returns an empty list again. And whatever combination I try, I either get an empty list or it's not working at all.

Does anyone have an idea, why this is or what else I could try? It's so frustrating to get that list of all ids but to not manage to select the one I need from the xsi:type...

#### EDIT:

I am getting the data via OAI and am using the following libraries and am using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. I've also tried `ElementTree` and `lxml`.

I literally just store the response from the API in a variable called "xml" and then try the following code, of which some works, and some doesn't:

```
ids = xml.find_all("identifier")[0].text
print(ids)

urn1 = xml.find_all("dc:identifier")
urn1 = urn1[0].text
print(urn1)

test1 = xml.find_all("dc:identifier")
print(test1)

urn2 = xml.find_all(".//dc:identifier")
print(urn2)

urn3 = xml.find_all("dc:identifier[@xsi:type='tel:URN']")
print(urn3)
```

First two return the text of the element as expected (I know that the first one is the isolated element in the header, not the first dc:identifier object, this just served testing purposes), the third part returns the list of all elements. The last two, on the other hand, return an empty list, and that is the problem (as I need the specific xsi:type-element specified in the last attempt.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: what library are you using? Post more of the code showing what is being used.

Comment: Upload a **VALID** xml please.

Comment: Code edited, valid xml there, but I don't think it will help much with the actual problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your xml is still not well formed since the `xsi` prefix hasn't been declared. I made up a declaration below just to make the answer work.

Second, you need to use an xml parser like lxml to use xpath.

So all together:

```
rec = """[your xml above, but with the first dc element now reading:
<dc xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xmlns:xsi="whatever" ...]"""

from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML(rec)
ns = {"dc":"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/",
      "xsi":"whatever"}
urn2 = doc.xpath("//dc:identifier/text()",namespaces=ns)
urn3 = doc.xpath("//dc:identifier[@xsi:type='tel:URN']/text()",namespaces=ns)
```

and that should do it

Comment: Thank you very much, that really helped! I am not sure why, but my xml (the response from the API) wasn't accepted initally by etree.XML but encoding it via content = r.encode() did the trick. I also had to add another namespace for DC, but it works now. Thank you! Still trying to get my head around all the encoding and transforming and accessing between xml, strings, xpath, etree etc... :D

Comment: @ssp24 Glad it worked for you and good luck on your educational journey....

Answer (score 1):

If you are using BeautifulSoup, the [`find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) method accepts the **element name**, not an XPath, for the first parameter.

> Method signature: find_all(name, attrs, recursive, string, limit, **kwargs)

If you want to use XPath, then you may need to look at other libraries.

See: [can we use XPath with BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11465555/14419)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned working with valid `XML` would make things much easier, but there is also a way to go with `BeautifulSoup` and its standard parser `lxml` - Well not with `xpath` but very close to your attempts.

Going with `find()` / `find_all()`:

```
soup.find_all('dc:identifier' , {'xsi:type':'tel:URN'})
```

get a list of texts:

```
[e.text for e in soup.find_all('dc:identifier' , {'xsi:type':'tel:URN'})]
```

---

While using `css selectors` with `select()` / `select_one()` instead of `find()` / `find_all()`you have to escape the `:`:

```
soup.select('dc\:identifier[xsi\:type="tel:URN"]')
```

to get a list of the texts combine with `list comprehension`:

```
[e.text for e in soup.select('dc\:identifier[xsi\:type="tel:URN"]')]
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml='''
<record>
<header>
<identifier>oai:dnb.de/dnb:reiheO/1254645608</identifier><datestamp>2022-04-01T23:49:32Z</datestamp>
<setspec>dnb:reiheO</setspec>
</header>
<metadata>
<dc xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dnb="http://d-nb.de/standards/dnbterms" xmlns:tel="http://krait.kb.nl/coop/tel/handbook/telterms.html">
<dc:title>Advantages of Simultaneous In Situ Multispecies Detection for Portable Emission Measurement Applications / Luigi Biondo, Henrik Gerken, Lars Illmann, Tim Steinhaus, Christian Beidl, Andreas Dreizler, Steven Wagner</dc:title>
<dc:identifier xsi:type="tel:URN">urn:nbn:de:tuda-tuprints-210508#fromFirstRecord</dc:identifier>
<dc:identifier xsi:type="tel:URL">http://nbn-resolving.de/urn:nbn:de:tuda-tuprints-210508</dc:identifier>
<dc:identifier xsi:type="tel:URL">http://d-nb.info/1254645608/34</dc:identifier>
<dc:identifier xsi:type="tel:URL">http://tuprints.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/21050/</dc:identifier>
<dc:identifier xsi:type="dnb:IDN">1254645608</dc:identifier>
<dc:subject>670 Industrielle und handwerkliche Fertigung</dc:subject>
<dc:rights>lizenzfrei</dc:rights>
<dc:type>Online-Ressource</dc:type>
</dc>
</metadata>
</record>
<record>
<header>
<identifier>oai:dnb.de/dnb:reiheO/1254645608</identifier><datestamp>2022-04-01T23:49:32Z</datestamp>
<setspec>dnb:reiheO</setspec>
</header>
<metadata>
<dc xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dnb="http://d-nb.de/standards/dnbterms" xmlns:tel="http://krait.kb.nl/coop/tel/handbook/telterms.html">
<dc:title>Advantages of Simultaneous In Situ Multispecies Detection for Portable Emission Measurement Applications / Luigi Biondo, Henrik Gerken, Lars Illmann, Tim Steinhaus, Christian Beidl, Andreas Dreizler, Steven Wagner</dc:title>
<dc:identifier xsi:type="tel:URN">urn:nbn:de:tuda-tuprints-210508#fromSecondRecord</dc:identifier>
<dc:identifier xsi:type="tel:URL">http://nbn-resolving.de/urn:nbn:de:tuda-tuprints-210508</dc:identifier>
<dc:identifier xsi:type="tel:URL">http://d-nb.info/1254645608/34</dc:identifier>
<dc:identifier xsi:type="tel:URL">http://tuprints.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/21050/</dc:identifier>
<dc:identifier xsi:type="dnb:IDN">1254645608</dc:identifier>
<dc:subject>670 Industrielle und handwerkliche Fertigung</dc:subject>
<dc:rights>lizenzfrei</dc:rights>
<dc:type>Online-Ressource</dc:type>
</dc>
</metadata>
</record>
'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)

[e.text for e in soup.select('dc\:identifier[xsi\:type="tel:URN"]')]
```

###### Output

```
['urn:nbn:de:tuda-tuprints-210508#fromFirstRecord',
 'urn:nbn:de:tuda-tuprints-210508#fromSecondRecord']
```