# Pandas and bs4 html scraping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am extracting data from an html file, it is in a table format so I made this line of code to convert all the tables to a data frame with pandas.

```
dfs = pd.read_html("synced_contacts.html")
```

Now, printing the 2nd row of tables of the data frame

```
dfs[1]
```

The output is the following:

[image]

How can I do so that the information is not duplicated in two columns as shown in the image, and also separate "First NameDaniela" in "First Name" as first column and "Daniela" as value

**Expected Output:**

[image]

**Table HTML structure:**

```html
<title>Synced contacts</title></head><body class="_5vb_ _2yq _a7o5"><div class="clearfix _ikh"><div class="_4bl9"><div class="_li"><div><table style="width:100%;background:white;position:fixed;z-index:99;"><tr style=""><td height="8" style="line-height:8px;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr style="background:white"><td style="text-align:left;height:28px;width:35px;"></td><td style="text-align:left;height:28px;"><img src="files/Instagram-Logo.png" height="28" alt="Instagram" /></td></tr><tr style=""><td height="5" style="line-height:5px;">&nbsp;</td></tr></table><div style="width:100%;height:44px;"></div></div><div class="_a705"><div class="_3-8y _3-95 _a70a"><div class="_a70d"><div class="_a70e">Synced contacts</div><div class="_a70f">Contacts you&#039;ve synced</div></div></div><div class="_a706" role="main"><div class="pam _3-95 _2ph- _a6-g uiBoxWhite noborder"><div class="_a6-p"><table style="table-layout: fixed;"><tr><td colspan="2" class="_2pin _a6_q">First Name<div><div>Daniela</div></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="_2pin _a6_q">Last Name<div><div>Guevara</div></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="_2pin _a6_q">Contact Information<div><div>3017004914</div></div></td></tr></table></div><div class="_3-94 _a6-o"></div></div><div class="pam _3-95 _2ph- _a6-g uiBoxWhite noborder"><div class="_a6-p"><table style="table-layout: fixed;"><tr><td colspan="2" class="_2pin _a6_q">First Name<div><div>Marianna</div></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="_2pin _a6_q">Contact Information<div><div>3125761972</div></div></td></tr></table></div><div class="_3-94 _a6-o"></div></div><div class="pam _3-95 _2ph- _a6-g uiBoxWhite noborder"><div class="_a6-p"><table style="table-layout: fixed;"><tr><td colspan="2" class="_2pin _a6_q">First Name<div><div>Ana Maria</div></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="_2pin _a6_q">Last Name<div><div>Garzon</div></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="_2pin _a6_q">Contact Information<div><div>3214948507</div></div></td></tr></table></div>
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample of the HTML document (in text form - so we can copy and paste it)?

Comment: can't help you without seeing your table html, but you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74090309/6146136) helpful if it's a nested table

Comment: I added the html table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by the struture, everything is placed in a single `<td>` and will be concatenated, the `colspan` is creating the second column.

`pd.read_html()` is a good for the first and easiest pass, not necessarily that it will handle every messy table in real life.

So instead using the `pd.read_html()` you could use `BeautifulSoup` directly to fit the behavior of how to scrape to your needs and create a `dataframe` from the result. [`.stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) is used here to split the texts of each element in the `<tr>` to a `list`.

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [
        dict([list(row.stripped_strings)for row in t.select('tr')]) 
        for t in soup.select('table:has(._2pin)')
    ]
)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''
<title>Synced contacts</title></head><body class="_5vb_ _2yq _a7o5"><div class="clearfix _ikh"><div class="_4bl9"><div class="_li"><div><table style="width:100%;background:white;position:fixed;z-index:99;"><tr style=""><td height="8" style="line-height:8px;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr style="background:white"><td style="text-align:left;height:28px;width:35px;"></td><td style="text-align:left;height:28px;"><img src="files/Instagram-Logo.png" height="28" alt="Instagram" /></td></tr><tr style=""><td height="5" style="line-height:5px;">&nbsp;</td></tr></table><div style="width:100%;height:44px;"></div></div><div class="_a705"><div class="_3-8y _3-95 _a70a"><div class="_a70d"><div class="_a70e">Synced contacts</div><div class="_a70f">Contacts you&#039;ve synced</div></div></div><div class="_a706" role="main"><div class="pam _3-95 _2ph- _a6-g uiBoxWhite noborder"><div class="_a6-p"><table style="table-layout: fixed;"><tr><td colspan="2" class="_2pin _a6_q">First Name<div><div>Daniela</div></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="_2pin _a6_q">Last Name<div><div>Guevara</div></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="_2pin _a6_q">Contact Information<div><div>3017004914</div></div></td></tr></table></div><div class="_3-94 _a6-o"></div></div><div class="pam _3-95 _2ph- _a6-g uiBoxWhite noborder"><div class="_a6-p"><table style="table-layout: fixed;"><tr><td colspan="2" class="_2pin _a6_q">First Name<div><div>Marianna</div></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="_2pin _a6_q">Contact Information<div><div>3125761972</div></div></td></tr></table></div><div class="_3-94 _a6-o"></div></div><div class="pam _3-95 _2ph- _a6-g uiBoxWhite noborder"><div class="_a6-p"><table style="table-layout: fixed;"><tr><td colspan="2" class="_2pin _a6_q">First Name<div><div>Ana Maria</div></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="_2pin _a6_q">Last Name<div><div>Garzon</div></div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="_2pin _a6_q">Contact Information<div><div>3214948507</div></div></td></tr></table></div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

pd.DataFrame(
    [
        dict([list(row.stripped_strings)for row in t.select('tr')]) 
        for t in soup.select('table:has(._2pin)')
    ]
)
```

##### Output

|  | First Name | Last Name | Contact Information |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Daniela | Guevara | 3017004914 |
| 1 | Marianna | nan | 3125761972 |
| 2 | Ana Maria | Garzon | 3214948507 |

Comment: Can you explain me how are you dividing the 'tr' concatenated sit¡rings in that dataframe dict?

Comment: Edited - stripped_strings is used here to simplify-> https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings but you cout also select the `divs` directly and extract the texts.