# How to scrape table using beautifulsoup only summary and width?

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table from this site.:http://wayback.archive-it.org/7993/20170110233205/http://www.fda.gov/Safety/Recalls/ArchiveRecalls/2015/default.htm

This table has no `id` or `class` and only contains summary and width. Is there any way to scrape this table?
Perhaps xpath?

I heard that xpath is not compatible with beautifulsoup and hope that is wrong.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="3" border="1" summary="Layout showing RecallTest table with 6 columns: Date,Brand Name,Product Description,Reason/Problem,Company,Details/Photo" style="margin-bottom:28px">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                    <th scope="col" data-type="numeric" data-toggle="true"> Date </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
```

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
link = 'http://wayback.archive-it.org/7993/20170110233205/http://www.fda.gov/Safety/Recalls/ArchiveRecalls/2015/default.htm'
page = 15
pdf = []
for p in range(1,page+1):
   l = link + '?page='+str(p)
    # Downloading contents of the web page
    data = requests.get(l).text
    # Creating BeautifulSoup object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    tables = soup.find_all('table')
    table = soup.find('table', INSERT XPATH EXPRESSION)
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['date','brand','descr','reason','company'])
    for row in table.tbody.find_all('tr'):    
        # Find all data for each column
        columns = row.find_all('td')
        if columns != []:
            date = columns[0].text.strip()
```

Comment: Does this answer helps you somewhat https://stackoverflow.com/a/11466033/3710053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scraping tables it is best practice to use `pandas.read_html()` that covers 95% of all cases. Simply iterate the sites and concat the `dataframes`:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://wayback.archive-it.org/7993/20170110233205/http://www.fda.gov/Safety/Recalls/ArchiveRecalls/2015/default.htm'

pd.concat(
    [pd.read_html(url+'?page='+str(i))[0]for i in range(1,16)],
    ignore_index=True
)
```

Note, that you can also include links via `extract_links='body'`

This will result in:

|  | Date | Brand Name | Product Description | Reason/Problem | Company | Details/Photo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12/31/2015 | PharMEDium | Norepinephrine Bitartrate added to Sodium Chloride | Discoloration | PharMEDium Services, LLC | nan |
| 1 | 12/31/2015 | Thomas Produce | Cucumbers | Salmonella | Thomas Produce Company | nan |
| 2 | 12/28/2015 | Wegmans, Uoriki Fresh | Octopus Salad | Listeria monocytogenes | Uoriki Fresh, Inc. | nan |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 433 | 01/05/2015 | Whole Foods Market | Assorted cookie platters | Undeclared tree nuts | Whole Foods Market | nan |
| 434 | 01/05/2015 | Eillien's, Blain's Farms and Fleet & more | Walnut Pieces | Salmonella contamination | Eillien’s Candies Inc. | nan |
| 435 | 01/02/2015 | Full Tilt Ice Cream | Ice Cream | Listeria monocytogenes | Full Tilt Ice Cream | nan |
| 436 | 01/02/2015 | Zilks | Hummus | Undeclared peanuts | Zilks Foods | nan |

Based on your manually approach simply select the first table, iterate over the rows and store information in a list of dicts , that could be simply converted into a dataframe:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://wayback.archive-it.org/7993/20170110233205/http://www.fda.gov/Safety/Recalls/ArchiveRecalls/2015/default.htm'

data = []

for i in range(1,16):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url+'?page='+str(i)).text)
    for e in soup.table.select('tr:has(td)'):
        data.append({
            'date': e.td.text,
            'any other': 'column',
            'link': e.a.get('href')
        })

data
```

Answer (score -2):

There is just two line of code to get the table from website

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "http://wayback.archive-it.org/7993/20170110233205/http://www.fda.gov/Safety/Recalls/ArchiveRecalls/2015/default.htm"
tables = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text)

print(tables[0])
```

You have to use two modules **requests** and **pandas**

you can read more about pandas.read_html function from [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)