# Unit testing using diff

Tags: unit-testing, diff

I have a program where the input is a complex file and the output is a changed file but in the same format. These files are of points and connections in 3D models. I need to be able to unit test this program without checking files line by line myself for equality. Something like a version control 'diff' would be ideal in terms of viewing differences but I don't know of a program or framework that could automate this process. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're a Perl person you might want to take a look at [Test::Files](http://search.cpan.org/~philcrow/Test-Files-0.14/Files.pm) that does file comparisons with a diff-style diagnostic output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `difflib` http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html

Related: [Comparing two .txt files using difflib in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977491/comparing-2-txt-files-using-difflib-in-python)