# Comparing two csv files and getting difference

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv file I need to compare and then spit out the differnces:

CSV FORMAT:

```
 Name   Produce   Number
 Adam   Apple     5
 Tom    Orange    4
 Adam   Orange    11
```

I need to compare the two csv files and then tell me if there is a difference between Adams apples on sheet and sheet 2 and do that for all names and produce numbers. Both CSV files will be formated the same.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: You've tagged this with `excel` but mention CSV files.  Do you need to work with xlsx or xls files?  You might find that `diff` works for want you need, but you haven't really said whether this needs to be done a lot and build into an existing python program.

Comment: Sorry you are correct will edit

Answer (score 8):

I have used csvdiff

```
$pip install csvdiff
$csvdiff --style=compact col1 a.csv b.csv
```

[Link to package on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/csvdiff)

[I found this link useful](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/csvdiff/latest/csvdiff.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

If your CSV files aren't so large they'll bring your machine to its knees if you load them into memory, then you could try something like:

```
import csv
csv1 = list(csv.DictReader(open('file1.csv')))
csv2 = list(csv.DictReader(open('file2.csv')))
set1 = set(csv1)
set2 = set(csv2)
print set1 - set2 # in 1, not in 2
print set2 - set1 # in 2, not in 1
print set1 & set2 # in both
```

For large files, you could load them into a SQLite3 database and use SQL queries to do the same, or sort by relevant keys and then do a match-merge.

Comment: The dicts in the csv1 list are not hashable so creating set1 will not be possible. This can be avoided by conversion of the dicts to strings with [json.dumps](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: @HK_CK okay I am happy for you to add that to answer... just not change it as you suggedted...

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'. Come on!

Answer (score 1):

One of the best utilities for comparing two different files is [`diff`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html).

See Python implementation here: [Comparing two .txt files using difflib in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977491/comparing-2-txt-files-using-difflib-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

def load_csv_to_dict(fname, get_key, get_data):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as inf:
        incsv = csv.reader(inf)
        incsv.next()  # skip header
        return {get_key(row):get_data(row) for row in incsv}

def main():
    key = lambda r: tuple(r[0:2])
    data = lambda r: int(r[2])
    f1 = load_csv_to_dict('file1.csv', key, data)
    f2 = load_csv_to_dict('file2.csv', key, data)

    f1keys = set(f1.iterkeys())
    f2keys = set(f2.iterkeys())

    print("Keys in file1 but not file2:")
    print(", ".join(str(a)+":"+str(b) for a,b in (f1keys-f2keys)))

    print("Keys in file2 but not file1:")
    print(", ".join(str(a)+":"+str(b) for a,b in (f2keys-f1keys)))

    print("Differing values:")
    for k in (f1keys & f2keys):
        a,b = f1[k], f2[k]
        if a != b:
            print("{}:{} {} <> {}".format(k[0],k[1], a, b))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: When I try this in IDLE I get this: http://pastebin.com/6U035ERr (Using pastebin so you can see the whole error message with formatting)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Python's csv module along with a function generator, you can use nested looping and compare large .csv files. The example below compares each row using a cursory comparision:

```
import csv

def csv_lazy_get(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile) as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        for row in r:
            yield row

def csv_cmp_lazy(csvfile1, csvfile2):
    gen_2 = csv_lazy_get(csvfile2)

    for row_1 in csv_lazy_get(csvfile1):
        row_2 = gen_2.next()

        print("row_1: ", row_1)
        print("row_2: ", row_2)

        if row_2 == row_1:
            print("row_1 is equal to row_2.")
        else:
            print("row_1 is not equal to row_2.")

    gen_2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a start that does not use `difflib`.  It is really just a point to build from because maybe Adam and apples appear twice on the sheet; can you ensure that is not the case?  Should the apples be summed, or is that an error?

```
import csv
fsock = open('sheet.csv','rU')
rdr = csv.reader(fsock)
sheet1 = {}
for row in rdr:
    name, produce, amount = row
    sheet1[(name, produce)] = int(amount) # always an integer?
fsock.close()
# repeat the above for the second sheet, then compare
```

You get the idea?