# Python TypeError: unhashable type: 'list''

Tags: python, parsing, csv, python-3.x

Been trying to get the difference between two CSV files in python. Want through a series of Tutorials but have been encountered with the same error on numerous occasions.

```
import csv

f1 = open ("ted.csv")
oldFile1 = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')
oldList1 = list(oldFile1)

f2 = open ("ted2.csv")
newFile2 = csv.reader(f2, delimiter=',')
newList2 = list(newFile2)

f1.close()
f2.close()

output1 = set(row for row in newList2 if row not in oldList1)
output2 = set(row for row in oldList1 if row not in newList2)



print (output2.difference(output1))
```

Traceback can be seen below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/tarts/testmrcsv.py", line 14, in <module>
output1 = set(row for row in newList2 if row not in oldList1)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

My objective is to create a 3rd csv file. Thanks

Comment: `difference` is a `set` method

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108667/comparing-two-csv-files-and-getting-difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` data type does not have any `difference` function, You may want to create `output1` and `output2` as set, Example -

```
output1 = set(row for row in newList2 if row not in oldList1)
output2 = set(row for row in oldList1 if row not in newList2)
```

If `row` is of type `list` , then you should also convert it to `tuple` before putting in the `set` . Example -

```
output1 = set(tuple(row) for row in newList2 if row not in oldList1)
output2 = set(tuple(row) for row in oldList1 if row not in newList2)
```

Comment: Im still getting an error with the format Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/tarts/testmrcsv.py", line 14, in <module>
    output1 = set(row for row in newList2 if row not in oldList1)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 0):

lists don't have the difference method but sets do:

```
>>> print(set(output2).difference(set(output1)))
```

Comment: Im getting Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/tarts/testmrcsv.py", line 14, in <module>
    output1 = set(row for row in newList2 if row not in oldList1)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'