# Find only the rows that exist in one csv but not the other

Tags: python, csv, awk

`CSV_1.csv` has the structure:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
PQR
```

`CSV_2.csv` has the structure:

```
XYZ
DEF
ABC
```

`CSV_2.csv` is a lot smaller than `CSV_1.csv` and a lot of the rows that exist in `CSV_2.csv` appears in `CSV_1.csv`. I want to figure out if there are rows that exist in `CSV_2.csv` but not in `CSV_1.csv`.

These files are not sorted.

The bigger csv has closer to 10 million rows, the smaller table has around 7 million rows.

How would I go about doing this? I tried python but taking each row from `CSV_2.csv` and comparing with 10 million rows in `CSV_1.csv` takes a lot of time.

Here is what I tried in python:

```
with open('old.csv', 'r') as t1, open('new.csv', 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open('update.csv', 'a') as outFile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)
```

`awk` comes to mind. What would the exact code be for `awk`?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239179/fastest-way-to-find-lines-of-a-text-file-from-another-larger-text-file-in-bash, it has lot of well researched answers. Pick the one that suits your needs

Comment: You can go through the following questions : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268929/python-comparing-two-csv-files-and-searching-for-similar-items

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108667/comparing-two-csv-files-and-getting-difference

Comment: @Inian The one you linked does not answer my question. I have also looked at other similar questions here on SO.

Comment: @user2125722 I already tried python. Very, very slow.

Comment: If you have tried python you should share, so that someone might help you with it.

Comment: @StephenRauch added.

Comment: @Inian No, I want the fastest solution, considering the size of both the files.

Comment: @Shoumik: Then suggest removing the `Awk` tag if you are not looking for an answer in it

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your approach is very inefficient. The following should be much faster, using `O(1)` lookup-time of sets, and iterating over the lines in `t2` lazily:

```
with open('old.csv', 'r') as t1, open('new.csv', 'r') as t2:
    fileone = frozenset(t1)

    with open('update.csv', 'a') as outFile:
        for line in t2:
            if line not in fileone:
                outFile.write(line)
```

Comment: Your solution gave me:

    fileone = frozenset(1)
    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @Shoumik that wasn't my solution, I wrote `fileone = frozenset(t1)`, so `frozenset(**t1**)` not `frozenset(1)`

Answer (score 0):

To speed up the python implementation, you should use a data structure which is fast for lookups.  You should try a `set`:

Change:

```
fileone = t1.readlines()
```

To:

```
fileone = set(t1.readlines())
```

This will considerably speed up the line:

```
if line not in fileone:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas dataframe.
Create 2 data frames from both the csv.

```
import pandas as pd
df1= pd.DataFrame.from_csv('CSV_1.csv')
df2= pd.DataFrame.from_csv('CSV_2.csv')
>>> df1
   val
0  ABC
1  DEF
2  GHI
3  JKL
4  MNO
5  PQR
>>> 
>>> df2
   val
0  XYZ
1  DEF
2  ABC
>>> df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
>>> df
   val      _merge
0  ABC        both
1  DEF        both
2  GHI   left_only
3  JKL   left_only
4  MNO   left_only
5  PQR   left_only
6  XYZ  right_only
>>> uniqueRowsInCsv2 = df[ df['_merge'] == 'right_only' ]
>>> uniqueRowsInCsv2
   val      _merge
6  XYZ  right_only
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could load the data in sets and use the set difference operation to speed up:

```
with open('old.csv', 'r') as t1, open('new.csv', 'r') as t2:
    old_set = set(t1.readlines())
    new_set = set(t2.readlines())

# values in new_set but not in old_set
differences =  new_set.difference(old_set)
with open('update.csv', 'a') as outFile:
    for difference in differences:
        outFile.write(difference)
```