# Comparing two files in python

Tags: python

I have the following code. I have checked other links on stackoverflow, but they are slightly complicated than mine.

For now my text files have `hello`(in file1) and `hell`(in file2) as data.

I believe my logic is correct but I get the following error

```
TypeError: object of type '_io.TextIOWrapper' has no len()
```

Where am I going wrong?

```
def compareString(line1,line2): #sub function to compare strings of files
    i=0 #initial index
    while line1[i]==line2[i]: #compare each line until they are equal
        i=i+1
    if line1[i]!=line2[i]: #if unequal
        print('Mismatch at character ',i,line1[i]) #print error message

def compareMain(): #
    file1=input('Enter the name of the first file: ') #input file1 name
    file2=input('Enter the name of the second file: ') #input file2 name

    fp1=open(file1,'r') #open file1, reading mode
    fp2=open(file2,'r') #open file2, reading mode
    for line1 in range(len(fp1)): #Getting each line of file1
        for line2 in range(len(fp2)): #Getting each line of file2
            compareString(line1,line2) #Call compare function
    fp1.close() #Close file1
    fp2.close() #Close file2

compareMain() #Execute
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use `range(len(fp1))`. You can use the `fp1` directly. That should fix the error.

```
def compareString(line1,line2): #sub function to compare strings of files
    i=0 #initial index
    while line1[i]==line2[i]: #compare each line until they are equal
        i=i+1
    if line1[i]!=line2[i]: #if unequal
        print('Mismatch at character ',i,line1[i]) #print error message

def compareMain(): #
    file1=input('Enter the name of the first file: ') #input file1 name
    file2=input('Enter the name of the second file: ') #input file2 name

    fp1=open(file1,'r') #open file1, reading mode
    fp2=open(file2,'r') #open file2, reading mode
    for line1 in fp1: #Getting each line of file1
        for line2 in fp2: #Getting each line of file2
            compareString(line1,line2) #Call compare function
    fp1.close() #Close file1
    fp2.close() #Close file2

compareMain() #Execute
```

Comment: That did. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Why don't u use `.read()`? This will give you the whole content of the file. And you can compare this content with content of second file. Which you can also get with `.read()`

Comment: @golobich I will try that approach as well. I am still new to python and programming overall.

Comment: You might consider using difflib (https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) for file comparison, since the way you are doing it could show all lines different if one file is missing the first line and all the rest of the lines are the same as in the other file. A code example of difflib usage is at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120489/compare-two-files-report-difference-in-python. If you just want to know if the contents of the files are the same or not, comparing checksums is efficient and so is filecmp (https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
def compare_files():
    file1=input('Enter the name of the first file: ') #input file1 name
    file2=input('Enter the name of the second file: ') #input file2 name
    fp1=open(file1,'r') #open file1, reading mode
    fp2=open(file2,'r') #open file2, reading mode
    if (fp1.read() == fp2.read()):
        print("Files are the same")
    else:
        print("Files are not the same")

compare_files()
```

Method `.read()` will return content of the file. We get content of both files and then we compare contents of this files.

Answer (score 0):

As Tris mentioned, I would suggest to use **difflib** (https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html). Here is the snippet that you may use to start:

```
import difflib
import sys

file1=sys.argv[1] 
file2=sys.argv[2]

line1 = open(file1).readlines()
line2 = open(file2).readlines()

line1_idx = 0
line2_idx = 0

for l1 in line1:
    l1 = l1.rstrip()
    line2_idx = 0
    for l2 in line2:
        l2 = l2.rstrip()
        diff = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, l1, l2)
        for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in diff.get_opcodes():
            if((tag == "delete") or (tag == "replace") or (tag == "insert")):
                print("Mismatch file1-line%d file2-line%d, line1-index[%d:%d] line2-index[%d:%d]" % (line1_idx, line2_idx, i1, i2, j1, j2))
        line2_idx += 1
    line1_idx += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I started this answer before I realized that the questioner wanted a diff, not just an identical-or-not check, but I figure this question might be found by people who do want that, so here it is. While the `main()` function works with only two files, the core code can work with any number of files. Either way, it'll only check up to the first line that doesn't match.

```
#
# Python 2/3 compatibility
#

from __future__ import print_function

try:
    from itertools import izip as zip  # Python 2
except ImportError:
    pass  # Python 3

try:
    input = raw_input  # Python 2
except NameError:
    pass  # Python 3


#
# You can leave out everything above if you're on Python 3
#

def all_equal(first_item, *items):
    return all(item == first_item for item in items)


def iterables_are_identical(*iterables):
    return all(all_equal(*tup) for tup in zip(*iterables))


def files_are_identical(*files, **kwargs):
    mode = kwargs.get('mode', 'r')

    open_files = []
    try:
        for f in files:
            open_files.append(open(f, mode))

        return iterables_are_identical(*open_files)
    finally:
        for handle in open_files:
            handle.close()


def main():
    msg = 'Enter the name of the %s file: '
    file_a = input(msg % 'first')
    file_b = input(msg % 'second')

    if files_are_identical(file_a, file_b):
        print('Files are identical')
    else:
        print('Files are NOT identical')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```