# How to diff between two HTML codes?

Tags: python, diff, lxml, difflib

I need to run a diff mechanism on two HTML page sources to kick out all the generated data (like user session, etc.).
I wondering if there is a python module that can do that diff  and return me the  element that contains the difference (So I will kick him in the rest of my code in another sources)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two files report difference in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120489/compare-two-files-report-difference-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing 2 .txt files using difflib in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977491/comparing-2-txt-files-using-difflib-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the difflib module. It's available as a part of standard python library.