# Python : Compare two csv files and print out differences

Tags: python, csv

I need to compare two CSV files and print out differences in a third CSV file.
In my case, the first CSV is a old list of hash named old.csv and the second CSV is the new list of hash which contains both old and new hash.

Here is my code :

```
import csv
t1 = open('old.csv', 'r')
t2 = open('new.csv', 'r')
fileone = t1.readlines()
filetwo = t2.readlines()
t1.close()
t2.close()

outFile = open('update.csv', 'w')
x = 0
for i in fileone:
    if i != filetwo[x]:
        outFile.write(filetwo[x])
    x += 1
outFile.close()
```

The third file is a copy of the old one and not the update.
What's wrong ? I Hope you can help me, many thanks !!

PS : i don't want to use diff

Comment: Not an answer, but a comment: under Linux, you can simply do `diff file1 file2` on the command line.

Comment: Look at `difflib` see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120489/compare-two-files-report-difference-in-python

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to use difflib

Comment: @NickYellow Why not?

Comment: You need to be more precise as to what a "difference" is and how to print it. What is a line is in the old file but not in the new? If a line is in the new file but not in the old? If two consecutive lines are swapped? If a line is moved to another position? Details like these make it hard to compare DNA sequences, for example, but you need to be sure exactly what you mean in your problem.

Comment: @Chris_Rands because I need to use CSV again for other things like SQL insert etc.

Comment: @Rory Daulton 
Difference :  I mean when a line is in the new file and is not in the old file,  if so write these line into a third file named "update" 
In the new file, a new entry (line) could appear everywhere is the CSV.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing each line in `fileone` to the same line in `filetwo`.  As soon as there is an extra line in one file you will find that the lines are never equal again.  Try this:

```
with open('old.csv', 'r') as t1, open('new.csv', 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)
```

Comment: @NickYellow No problem.  FYI, it is generally best practice to use the `with open() as` statement to open files so that they are closed properly if any errors occur.

Answer (score 24):

You may find this package useful ([csv-diff](https://pypi.org/project/csv-diff/)):

```
pip install csv-diff
```

Once installed, you can run it from the command line:

```
csv-diff one.csv two.csv --key=id
```

Comment: awesome library - easy to use and data is nicely outputted

Comment: How may I import it? For use in jupyter noteboook

Comment: @SnehaaGanesan https://github.com/simonw/csv-diff has example of using as a python library

Comment: I was getting a `Click discovered that you exported a UTF-8 locale but the locale system could not pick up from it because it does not exist. The exported locale is 'en_US.UTF-8' but it is not supported.` on running csv-diff command. To counter this specific error, check the output of `locale`. `LC_ALL` may not have been set in the system locale. You can export the env variable `LC_ALL` according to your desired config. E.g: `export LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8`. After this export command, my csv-diff command started working.

Answer (score 10):

It feels natural detecting differences using sets.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import argparse
import csv


def get_dataset(f):
    return set(map(tuple, csv.reader(f)))


def main(f1, f2, outfile, sorting_column):
    set1 = get_dataset(f1)
    set2 = get_dataset(f2)
    different = set1 ^ set2

    output = csv.writer(outfile)

    for row in sorted(different, key=lambda x: x[sorting_column], reverse=True):
        output.writerow(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('infile', nargs=2, type=argparse.FileType('r'))
    parser.add_argument('outfile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('w'), default=sys.stdout)
    parser.add_argument('-sc', '--sorting-column', nargs='?', type=int, default=0)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(*args.infile, args.outfile, args.sorting_column)
```

Answer (score 6):

I assumed your new file was just like your old one, except that some lines were added in between the old ones. The old lines in both files are stored in the same order.

Try this :

```
with open('old.csv', 'r') as t1:
    old_csv = t1.readlines()
with open('new.csv', 'r') as t2:
    new_csv = t2.readlines()

with open('update.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    line_in_new = 0
    line_in_old = 0
    while line_in_new < len(new_csv) and line_in_old < len(old_csv):
        if old_csv[line_in_old] != new_csv[line_in_new]:
            out_file.write(new_csv[line_in_new])
        else:
            line_in_old += 1
        line_in_new += 1
```

- Note that I used the context manager `with` and some meaningful variable names, which makes it instantly easier to understand. And you don't need the `csv` package since you're not using any of its functionalities here.
- About your code, you were almost doing the right thing, except that _you must not go to the next line in your old CSV unless you are reading the same thing in both CSVs. That is to say, if you find a new line, keep reading the new file until you stumble upon an old one and then you'll be able to continue reading.

**UPDATE:** This solution is not as pretty as [Chris Mueller's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38996374/5018771) which is perfect and very Pythonic for small files, but it only reads the files once (keeping the idea of your original algorithm), thus it can be better if you have larger file.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import csv

def dataframe_difference(df1: pd.DataFrame, df2: pd.DataFrame, csvfile, which=None):
    """Find rows which are different between two DataFrames."""
    comparison_df = df1.merge(
        df2,
        indicator=True,
        how='outer'
    )
    if which is None:
        diff_df = comparison_df[comparison_df['_merge'] != 'both']
    else:
        diff_df = comparison_df[comparison_df['_merge'] == which]
    diff_df.to_csv(csvfile)
    return diff_df


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df1 = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1], sep=',')    
    df2 = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[2], sep=',')

    df1.sort_values(sys.argv[3])
    df2.sort_values(sys.argv[3])
    #df1.drop(df1.columns[list(map(int, sys.argv[4].split()))], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    #df2.drop(df2.columns[list(map(int, sys.argv[4].split()))], axis = 1, inplace = True)

    print(dataframe_difference(df1, df2, sys.argv[5]))
```

**to use run**:

```sh
python3 script.py file1.csv file2.csv some_common_header_to_sort_each_file output_file.csv
```

In case you want to drop any columns from comparasion, uncomment `df.drop` part and run

```sh
python3 script.py file1.csv file2.csv some_common_header_to_sort_each_file "x y z..." output_file.csv
```

where `x,y,z` are the column numbers to drop, index starts from 0.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @vishnoo-rath's comment under one of the above answers, for providing a link to the following page :
https://github.com/simonw/csv-diff#as-a-python-library

```
from csv_diff import load_csv, compare
diff = compare(
    load_csv(open("one.csv"), key="id"),
    load_csv(open("two.csv"), key="id")
)
print(diff)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('first_test_pipe.csv', 'r') as t1, open('validation.csv', 'r') as t2:
    filecoming = t1.readlines()
    filevalidation = t2.readlines()

for i in range(0,len(filevalidation)):
    coming_set = set(filecoming[i].replace("\n","").split(","))
    validation_set = set(filevalidation[i].replace("\n","").split(","))
    ReceivedDataList=list(validation_set.intersection(coming_set))
    NotReceivedDataList=list(coming_set.union(validation_set)- 
    coming_set.intersection(validation_set))
    print(NotReceivedDataList)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('fileone.csv', 'r') as r1, open('filetwo.csv', 'r') as r2, open('filethree.csv', 'w', newline='') as r3:
    old_csv = r1.readlines()
    new_csv = r2.readlines()        

#For example, If you want to add headers in the third file , use like below.
fieldnames = ['Configuration','Host','IPAddress','Account','Profile','Version','Type','OS']
compare_csv = csv.DictWriter(r3, fieldnames=fieldnames)
compare_csv.writeheader()
for row2 in old_csv:
    if row2 not in new_csv:
        r3.write(row2)
```