# Compare 2 CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having difficulty comparing two CSV files and printing out a separate report. I want my script to first match the IDs on the two files then compare the rest of row and print out a separate report showing the difference. The script I have compares two files and prints difference but won't work if the new file has additional rows.

example of the two files:

*OLD file*

```
ID  fname   lname   status
1   joe pol active
2   peters  dol active
3   john    nol active
4   mike    sol active
```

*New file*

```
ID  fname   lname   status
1   joe pol active
2   peter   dol active
67  ryan    olson   stop
3   johnny  nolly   stop 
4   mike    sol active
```

Code:

```
import csv

orig = open('OLD.csv','r')
new = open('NEW.csv','r')

Change = set(new) - set(orig)

print(Change)

with open('OLD.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    with open('different.csv', 'w') as file_out:
        for line in Change:
            file_out.write(line)

orig.close()
new.close()
file_out.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python : Compare two csv files and print out differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996033/python-compare-two-csv-files-and-print-out-differences)

Comment: What output file showing the differences are you expecting from those two files?

Comment: @RoadRunner changes between the two csv files going by the ID and checking the corresponding rows

Comment: @TheInfectedDrake Thank you but that one doesnt go by unique ID

Comment: @ben I see. Also those files are not CSV files. CSV files need to be comma separated.

Comment: @RoadRunner This is perfect! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CSV files need to comma separated, I'm assuming your files can be in this format:

*old.csv:*

```
ID,fname,lname,status
1,joe,pol,active
2,peters,dol,active
3,john,nol,active
4,mike,sol,active
```

*new.csv:*

```
ID,fname,lname,status
1,joe,pol,active
2,peter,dol,active
67,ryan,olson,stop
3,johnny,nolly,stop
4,mike,sol,active
```

Then you can convert them into a report with this code:

```
from csv import reader


# Creates a row dictionary from file
def get_row_map(filename):
    row_map = {}

    with open(filename) as file:
        csv_reader = reader(file)
        _, *headers = next(csv_reader)

        # map ids to rows
        for row in csv_reader:
            idx, *rest = row
            row_map[int(idx)] = dict(zip(headers, rest))

    return row_map


old_row_map = get_row_map("old.csv")
new_row_map = get_row_map("new.csv")

with open("different.txt", "w") as out:

    # Only loop over matched ids
    for row_id in old_row_map.keys() & new_row_map.keys():

        # only proceed if rows are not exactly the same
        if old_row_map[row_id] != new_row_map[row_id]:

            # convert to sets
            old_set, new_set = (
                set(old_row_map[row_id].items()),
                set(new_row_map[row_id].items()),
            )

            # get differences between old and new sets
            old_diff = dict(list(old_set - new_set))
            new_diff = dict(list(new_set - old_set))

            # write out report
            out.write("ID: %d\n" % row_id)
            for key in old_diff:
                out.write(
                    "%s -> old: %s, new: %s\n" % (key, old_diff[key], new_diff[key])
                )
```

Which Outputs the following *difference.txt:*

```
ID: 2
fname -> old: peters, new: peter
ID: 3
fname -> old: john, new: johnny
lname -> old: nol, new: nolly
status -> old: active, new: stop
```