# comparing two files in python using csvreader

Tags: python, csvreader

I am reading two csv files and comparing the 2 col in these files.

```
enroll_file_read = open(enroll_feed_modified, "r", encoding="utf-8")
drop_file_read = open(drop_feed_modified, "r", encoding="utf-8")
enroll_csvreader = csv.reader(enroll_file_read)
drop_csvreader = csv.reader(drop_file_read)
for row in enroll_csvreader:
    print(row[1])
    for row_1 in drop_csvreader:
        print("inside second loop")
        if(row[1] == row_1[1] and row[3] == row_1[3]):
            print(*row_1,sep="|")
```

Both the files have comma separated contents. Not sure why its not entering into second for loop. I am seeing only the print of row[1]. Am i missing anything here. This CSV file is generated from oracle DB.
When print them separately its priting without any issues.

Need some advise.

Comment: Can you provide the CSV sample files?]

Comment: See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38996374/2570277