# I want to compare 2 csv files that is file 1 and file 2 on basis of column

Tags: python, csv, sorting

I want to compare 2 csv files that is file 1 and file 2 on basis of column. If column of file 1 matches with column of file 2 then remove that entire row of file 1.

Example of file 1

```
sr. no.,username,id
101,Berlin240,835070687
102,X_PSYCH_X,1271001789 
103,xenoo369,570078204
104,xarat581,1665916522
105,xandy88,639040049
```

Example of file 2:

```
sr. no.,username,id
101,Berlin240,835070687
103,xenoo369,570078204
105,xandy88,639040049
```

Now comparing file2 and removing all rows in file 1 that matches with the column of file 1.

Now the file1 looks like this:

```
sr. no.,username,id
102,X_PSYCH_X,1271001789
104,xarat581,1665916522
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried, and let us know what part of your code isn't working or what challenges you're running into?

Comment: actually dont know where to start

Comment: No worries, it appears to be your problem is similar to another post. Try reviewing this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996033/python-compare-two-csv-files-and-print-out-differences). Once you have a specific problem with the code, feel free to create another post or update this one

Answer (score 1):

The following code is a python solution.  First install pandas.  You can probably accomplish this with the command

```
>>> pip install pandas
```

The code is ....

```py
import pandas as pd

file1_path = r"D:\Development\Test\file1.csv"
file2_path = r"D:\Development\Test\file2.csv"

df1 = pd.read_csv(file1_path)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2_path)

new_df = df1[~df1['id'].isin(df2['id'])]

print(new_df)

new_df.to_csv(file1_path)  # saving difference in file1
```

To see the output open your file1.
**output:**

```
   sr. no.    username          id
     102     X_PSYCH_X    1271001789
     104     xarat581     1665916522
```

Answer (score -1):

## solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("df1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("df2.csv")

print(df1)
print(df2)

df_diff = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

print(df_diff)
```

## df1

```
     sr. no.  username      id
0      101  Berlin240   835070687
1      102  X_PSYCH_X  1271001789
2      103   xenoo369   570078204
3      104   xarat581  1665916522
4      105    xandy88   639040049
```

## df2

```
     sr. no.  username     id
0      101  Berlin240  835070687
1      103   xenoo369  570078204
2      105    xandy88  639040049
```

## df_diff

```
     sr. no.  username      id
1      102  X_PSYCH_X  1271001789
3      104   xarat581  1665916522
```

Comment: but i want to compare using id of a column