# iterating over rows in a dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   VID  CID  PID8  PID6
0    1  379     3     3
1    2  160     2     2
2    3  334     3     3
3    7  176     1     3
4    8  237     3     2
```

I need to find the changes from PID6 to PID8

I have tried this so far:

```
import pandas as pd
vp = pd.read_csv('votingpattern.csv') 
print vp.head()
print type(vp)
for v in VID:
    if vp.PID6 == 1 & vp.PID8 == 2:
        C12 += 1
    elif vp.PID6 == 1 & vp.PID8 == 3:
        C13 += 1
    elif vp.PID6 == 2 & vp.PID8 == 3:
        C23 += 1
    elif vp.PID6 == 2 & vp.PID8 == 1:
        C21 += 1
    elif vp.PID6 == 3 & vp.PID8 == 1:
        C31 += 1
    else vp.PID6 == 3 & vp.PID8 == 2:
        C32 += 1

MyList = [C12,C13,C23,C21,C31,C32]
print max(MyList)
```

But I can't seem to access the entire row of dataframe and iterate over each row.
Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120489/compare-two-files-report-difference-in-python

Comment: You can post it as and answer and accept it in a bit.

Comment: and you should look into for loops. They will help you shorten that code a LOT!

Comment: I need to gain special insights about the changes hence did it this way, so that I may access individual variable for a specific pattern. Can loop help me do the same?

Comment: for i in range (0,n):
    if vp.PID6[i] == 1 & vp.PID8[i] == 2: 
        C12 += 1
    elif vp.PID6[i] == 1 & vp.PID8[i] == 3:
        C13 += 1..........

Adding a loop worked...@AllDani.com Thanks!

Comment: No problem. You can post that as an answer, and accept it.