# Check if there are new strings in a txt file

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a function which will compare two `txt` files. If it recognizes new lines that are in one file but not in the other, it will add them in a `list` and also in that file that does not contain those new lines. It fails to do that. Here is my function. What am I doing wrong?

```
newLinks = []

def newer():
with open('cnbcNewLinks.txt', 'w') as newL:
    for line in open('cnbcCleanedLinks.txt'):
        if line not in "cnbcNewLinks.txt":
            newLinks.append(line)
            newL.write(line)
        else:
            continue
cleaned = ''.join(newLinks)
print(cleaned)
```

Comment: `if line not in "cnbcNewLinks.txt":` is just testing the text string of the filename, it is *not* searching the file.

Comment: How can I search for new strings then?

Comment: Use the file handle `newL`, as you already do when writing to the file.

Comment: Not a very efficient way of doing it, but you could just change `if line not in "cnbcNewLinks.txt"` to `if line not in open("cnbcNewLinks.txt").readlines()` and it should probably work. A more pragmatic way would be to have a double loop.

Comment: It says: " 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines' "

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120489/compare-two-files-report-difference-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put in python code what @Alex suggested.

See the doc for [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

I replace you text file name by `a.txt` and `b.txt` to be easily readable.

```
# First read the files and compare then using `set`
with open('a.txt', 'r') as newL, open('b.txt', 'r') as cleanL:
    a = set(newL)
    b = set(cleanL)
    add_to_cleanL = list(a - b) # list with line in newL that are not in cleanL
    add_to_newL = list(b - a) # list with line in cleanL that are not in newL

# Then open in append mode to add at the end of the file
with open('a.txt', 'a') as newL, open('b.txt', 'a') as cleanL:
    newL.write(''.join(add_to_newL)) # append the list at the end of newL
    cleanL.write(''.join(add_to_cleanL)) # append the list at the end of cleanL
```

Answer (score 1):

If files not big, then move data in list,
both of list convert in set and use 'differ' builtin functions, two times.
then add difference in files.