# Stock Data Storage and calculation using python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with stock data which i download using a file everyday. The file contains the same no of columns everyday but the rows would change everyday depending up the stocks in and out of the list. I am looking to compare the files from 2 dates and find the difference between the total quantity column. I want to see the difference between the two files which stocks got in or got out of the list.

I have tried using pandas dataframe and storing it in a hd5 file. Then tried merge function of the dataframes to find the differences between the two file. I am looking for a much elegant solution so that i can compare data frames and find the differences like i do it using index and match(or vlookup) function of excel.

Comment: In what format is the file you receive ?

Comment: This is very broad. To get any meaningful answer you should include file types, sample input / output, why you think your current solution is inelegant etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the python [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#module-difflib) library to compare the files.

From the documentation:

> This module provides classes and functions for comparing sequences. It can be used for example, for **comparing files**, and can produce difference information in various formats, including HTML and context and unified diffs

Also, look at the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19120489/2570277) similar question for some examples. One example that may be useful in your case is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32629026/2570277).