# If a text that is inside of File 1 that is also inside of File 2, write to a new file without the duplicates

Tags: python

file.txt
file2.txt

I'm trying to make a Python script that will do the following:

Read file.txt and file2.txt
If there is something that is inside of file.txt which is also inside of file2.txt, remove it from file.txt

This is what I've done:

```
file1 = open('file.txt', 'r').readlines()
file2 = open('file2.txt', 'r').readlines()
Removed = open('Removed.txt', 'a')
for line in file2:
    if line not in file1:
        Removed.write(str(line) + '\n')
Removed.close()
```

It just removed it from file2.txt

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. Please read the following documentation, then [edit] and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Merge two files, sort them and write unique entries into a new.

Comment: Do you need to keep the lines in the same order?

Comment: @MarkRansom basically I wan t it to check if there is something that is inside of file.txt which is also inside of file2.txt, make a new file named removed.txt for example and write   everything inside of file1 but like if there is anything inside of file2 remove it from file1 and write into a new file

Comment: @MarkRansom I don't mean like remove the from the file itself not physically just mentally and rewrite it without it

Comment: [Compare two files report difference in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120489/compare-two-files-report-difference-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of the lines in `file.txt` after cleaning the duplicate data, you could use a [set difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) between the two file's lines (after converting them to `set` objects). Try something as follows:

```
with open('f1.txt') as f1, open('f2.txt') as f2:
    f1_lines = set(f1.read().splitlines())
    f2_lines = set(f2.read().splitlines())

new_data = f1_lines - f2_lines

with open('f1.txt', 'w') as f1:
    f1.write("\n".join(new_data))
```

Comment: It works thank you but is there a way to do from top to bottom/

Comment: You're welcome. What do you mean by "from top to bottom"?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is fine, but it will be very slow.  The line `if line not in file1:` will do a linear scan of the list for every line in `file2`.  If you make it a set things will go much faster, because sets don't need to do a linear scan.

```
file1 = set(open('file.txt', 'r').readlines())
```

You will also want to close the files after you've read them, or better yet use a `with` statement so they get automatically closed.

Comment: It works but it doesn't do what I'm aiming for, I want to write every single thing in file1 apart from if any line is in file2.

This code just prints the duplicate in between the files

Comment: @Zenzureal then fix your original code, because it doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for... it also keeps the line orders:

```
with open('file.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2:
    file1_lines = (f1.read().splitlines())
    file2_lines = (f2.read().splitlines())

for line in file1_lines:
    if line in file2_lines:
        file1_lines.remove(line)
    
with open('Removed.txt', 'w') as f3:
    f3.write("\n".join(file1_lines))
```

> to check if there is something that is inside of file.txt which is
> also inside of file2.txt, make a new file named removed.txt for
> example and write everything inside of file1 but like if there is
> anything inside of file2 remove it from file1 and write into a new
> file – @Zenzureal