# Check file has changed or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, operating-system

My requirement is to checks to see if a file has changed since the last run.
I have made an attempt to do with this `os.stat` and I'm not sure whether it is a correct way or not.

```
import os
import json

file_info = os.stat("cli.py")
with open("log.txt", "r") as file:
    line = json.loads(file.readline())
    if list(set(line)-set(list(file_info))):
       print("Changes in file")
       with open ("log.txt", "w+") as f:
           f.write(str(list(file_info)))
```

I looking for is there any better ideas or am I doing it in correct way or not. Any help is appreciated

Comment: are you comparing the full file content line for line? why not comparing checksums, e.g md5

Comment: Have u seen this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/182197/7636315 .. It talks abt variety of methods for this purpose like polling (performance concerns), QfileSystemWatcher (depends on pyqt), Watchdog (python api library) etc. This should help u i think.

Comment: @MarcelZoll No I'am comparing the file info like modified date, inod no with the info stored in a file when last runs, Its not the file contents. I don't have any idea about checksums or md5 .

Answer (score 2):

You can use a checksum, e.g. MD5

```
import hashlib

with open("yourfile", "rb") as f:

    print(hashlib.md5(f.read()).hexdigest())
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html

If you need to know where the file has changed use [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html), shipped with Python. For links to examples see comments.

Comment: So does it show the changes in file since last run of this script ?

Comment: This only shows if the file has changed not where. To see where it changed use the difflib, also shipped with Python.
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/difflib.html

Comment: There are many examples around, e.g. https://www.smallsurething.com/comparing-files-in-python-using-difflib/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977491/comparing-two-txt-files-using-difflib-in-python

Comment: So how does this tell us the file has changed? When the checksum changes?