# Get unique lines in two text files

Tags: python, text, duplicates

I have two unsorted text files (between 150MB and 1GB in size).

I want to find all the lines that are present in `a.txt` and **not** in `b.txt`.

`a.txt` contains-->

```
qwe
asd
zxc
rty
```

`b.txt` contains-->

```
qwe
zxc
```

If I combine `a.txt` and 'b.txt`in`c.txt` I get:

```
qwe
asd
zxc
rty
qwe
zxc
```

I sort them alphabetically and get:

```
asd
qwe
qwe
rty
zxc
zxc
```

Then I use regx mode to search for (.*)\n(\1)\n and replace them all with null and then I replace all \n\n multiple times with \n to get the "difference" between two files.

Now I am unable to do so in python. I am able to do it till the sorting part but regular expressions doesn't seems to be working in multi-lines.
Here is my python code

```
f = open("output.txt", 'w')
s = open(outputfile,'r+')
for line in s.readlines():
    s = line.replace('(.*)\n(\1)\n', '')
    f.write(s)

f.close()
```

Comment: That's... a rather inefficient and round-about way of finding the difference. Why not use sets?

Comment: And you are matching against *each individual line*, so no, you can't then use a regex that requires there to be at least *two* lines to work.

Comment: It would be better to use a library than writing the diff logic on your own. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977491/comparing-two-txt-files-using-difflib-in-python

Comment: @MartijnPieters How do I cancel them using sets

Comment: Can I store two lines in a single variable by using any means?

Comment: @serbia99 I was just applying what I used in Sublime directly. Will try that library too... Thanks !

Comment: @serbia99: difflib might be overkill if all they want is to detect lines missing in the other file.

Comment: There are 1500k lines and 1400k lines in other. All they want is another file containing the missing ones. @serbia99

Comment: @SanjayWadhwa: that's not enough lines to create 1GB of file size. That's no more than about 60 kb all lines combined, if your lines are under 20 characters in length.

Comment: Are the lines *unique* in files a and b? In other words, will there only ever be *at most* 2 consecutive lines that are the same in c.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am able to do it till the sorting part but regular expressions doesn't seems to be working in multi-lines.

Your regex is fine. You *don't have multi-lines*. You have **single** lines:

```
for line in s.readlines():
```

`file.readlines()` reads all of a file into memory as a list of lines. You then the iterates over *each of those single lines*, so `line` will be `'asd\n'` or `'qwe\n'`, and *never* `'qwe\nqwe\n'`.

Given that you are reading all of your merged file into memory, I'm going to presume that your files are not that big. In that case, it'd be *much easier* to just read one of those files into a set object, then just test each line of the other file to find the differences:

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as file_a:
    lines = set(file_a)  # all lines, as a set, with newlines

new_in_b = []
with open('b.txt', 'r') as file_b:
    for line in file_b:
        if line in lines:
            # present in both files, remove from `lines` to find extra lines in a
            lines.remove(line)
        else:
            # extra line in b
            new_in_b.append(line)

print('Lines in a missing from b')
for line in sorted(lines):
    print(line.rstrip())  # remove the newline when printing.
print()

print('Lines in b missing from a')
for line in new_in_b:
    print(line.rstrip())  # remove the newline when printing.
print()
```

If you wanted to write those all out to a file, you could just combine the two sequences and write out the sorted list:

```
with open('c.txt', 'w') as file_c:
    file_c.writelines(sorted(list(lines) + new_in_b))
```

Your approach, sorting your lines first, putting them all in a file, and then matching paired lines, is possible too. All you need to do is remember the *preceding line*. Together with the current line, that's a pair. Note that you *don't need a regular expression for this*, just an equality test:

```
with open('c.txt', 'r') as file_c, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    preceding = None
    skip = False
    for line in file_c:
        if preceding and preceding == line:
            # skip writing this line, but clear 'preceding' so we don't
            # check the next line against it
            preceding = None
        else:
            outfile.write(preceding)
            preceding = line
    # write out the last line
    if preceding:
        outfile.write(preceding)
```

Note that this never reads the whole file into memory! Iteration directly over the file gives you individual lines, where the file is read in chunks into a buffer. This is a very efficient method of processing lines.

You can also iterate over the file two lines at a time using the [`itertools` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to tee off the file object iterator:

```
with open('c.txt', 'r') as file_c, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    iter1, iter2 = tee(file_c)  # two iterators with shared source
    line2 = next(iter2, None)  # move second iterator ahead a line
    # iterate over this and the next line, and add a counter
    for i, (line1, line2) in enumerate(zip(iter1, iter2)):
        if line1 != line2:
            outfile.write(line1)
        else:
            # clear the last line so we don't try to write it out
            # at the end
            line2 = None
    # write out the last line if it didn't match the preceding
    if line2:
        outfile.write(line2)
```

A third approach is to use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group lines that are equal together. You can then decide what to do with those groups:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('c.txt', 'r') as file_c, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line, group in groupby(file_c):
        # group is an iterator of all the lines in c that are equal
        # the same value is already in line, so all we need to do is
        # *count* how many such lines there are:
        count = sum(1 for line in group)  # get an efficient count
        if count == 1:
            # line is unique, write it out
            outfile.write(line)
```

I'm assuming that it doesn't matter if there are 2 or more copies of the same line. In other words, you don't want *pairing*, you want to only find the unique lines (those only present in a or b).

If your files are extremely large *but already sorted*, you can use a merge sort approach, *without* having to merge your two files into one manually. The [`heapq.merge()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) gives you lines from multiple files in sorted order provided the *inputs* are sorted individually. Use this together with `groupby()`:

```
import heapq
from itertools import groupby

# files a.txt and b.txt are assumed to be sorted already
with open('a.txt', 'r') as file_a, open('b.txt', 'r') as file_b,\
        open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line, group in groupby(heapq.merge(file_a, file_b)):
        count = sum(1 for line in group)
        if count == 1:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Again, these approaches only read enough data from each file to fill a buffer. The `heapq.merge()` iterator only holds two lines in memory at a time, as does `groupby()`. This lets you process files of any size, regardless of your memory constraints.

Comment: My files are are in the range of 150 MBs to 1 GB, all containing image file name in different line like 201805002113_P.jpg

Comment: @SanjayWadhwa: that's up to 50 million lines then, that does become a little.. large. Are your input files sorted at all?

Comment: @SanjayWadhwa: your own approach can't handle that very well either, because you are reading *all lines of `c.txt` into memory*. With up to 100 million lines (two 1GB files of filenames) you *will* run out of memory.

Comment: I know my approach will not work... And no... they aren't sorted at all

Comment: @SanjayWadhwa: I'd get them sorted then; there are efficient command-line tools that can get you a sorted file output. Even if you only sort *subsets of each file*, you can use `heapq.merge()` to sort together any number of subsets if each subset is sorted.